# push_back vs emplace_back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, c++11, move-semantics

I'm a bit confused regarding the difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back`.

```
void emplace_back(Type&& _Val);
void push_back(const Type& _Val);
void push_back(Type&& _Val);
```

As there is a `push_back` overload taking a rvalue reference I don't quite see what the purpose of `emplace_back` becomes?

Comment: Some good reading here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2642.pdf

Comment: Note that (as Thomas says below), the code in the question is from MSVS's *emulation* of C++0x, not what C++0x actually is.

Comment: A better paper to read would be: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2345.pdf. N2642 is mostly wording for the Standard; N2345 is the paper that explains and motivates the idea.

Comment: Note that even in MSVC10 there is a `template <class _Valty> void emplace_back(_Valty&& _Val)` version that takes a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) which provides perfect forwarding to `explicit` single argument constructors.

Comment: Related: Is there any case where `push_back` is preferable to `emplace_back`? The only case I can think of is if a class were somehow copyable (`T&operator=(constT&)`) but not construct-able (`T(constT&)`), but I can't think of why one would ever want that.

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890653/why-would-i-ever-use-push-back-instead-of-emplace-back).

Comment: @Ben Everyone else (if I may presume) interprets an unqualified "copyable" to mean copy-constructible, not copy-assignable as you showed. Both `emplace_back()` and `push_back()` will invoke the copy-constructor - i.e. both perform construction, i.e. neither perform assignment - so your suggested class would not fare any better with either.

Comment: The related case I tripped over (that I mentioned just now in a separate thread on this page) is that `emplace_back` will "implicitly" call `explicit` constructors, which could lead to undesired behavior. (For heavy classes, I often make the copy c'tor `explicit` leaving the move-c'tor implicit. `v.emplace_back(x)` bit me by doing basically `v.emplace_back(X(x))` when I hoped it to error and force me to write `v.push_back(std::move(x))`.)

Comment: *Excellent* and easy-to-understand answer here: https://www.quora.com/In-what-scenarios-should-I-use-emplace_back-instead-of-push_back-in-C%2B%2B/answer/Kevin-Mather?ch=10&share=46e9e37c&srid=CWXc

Comment: Related: [Why would I ever use push_back instead of emplace_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890653/why-would-i-ever-use-push-back-instead-of-emplace-back/10890716)

Comment: two series of articles on this topic : 
https://medium.com/@its.me.siddh/modern-c-series-vector-push-back-or-emplace-back-e3a482ab4dcd    

https://medium.com/@its.me.siddh/modern-c-series-vector-push-back-or-emplace-back-part2-1ad564a5711b

Answer (score 831, accepted):

In addition to what visitor said :

The function `void emplace_back(Type&& _Val)` provided by MSCV10 is non-conforming and redundant because as you noted it is strictly equivalent to `push_back(Type&& _Val)`.

But the real C++0x form of `emplace_back` is really useful: [`void emplace_back(Args&&...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back);

Instead of taking a `value_type`, it takes a variadic list of arguments, so that means that you can now perfectly forward the arguments and construct directly an object into a container without a temporary at all.

That's useful because no matter how much cleverness RVO and move semantics bring to the table, there are still complicated cases where a `push_back` is likely to make unnecessary copies (or move). For example, with the traditional `insert()` function of a `std::map`, you have to create a temporary, which will then be copied into a `std::pair<Key, Value>`, which will then be copied into the map :

```
std::map<int, Complicated> m;
int anInt = 4;
double aDouble = 5.0;
std::string aString = "C++";
    
// cross your finger so that the optimizer is really good
m.insert(std::make_pair(4, Complicated(anInt, aDouble, aString))); 

// should be easier for the optimizer
m.emplace(4, anInt, aDouble, aString);
```

So why didn't they implement the right version of `emplace_back` in MSVC? Actually, it bugged me too a while ago, so I asked the same question on the [Visual C++ blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/vcblog/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-is-now-available-for-download). Here is the answer from Stephan T Lavavej, the official maintainer of the Visual C++ standard library implementation at Microsoft.

> Q: Are beta 2 emplace functions just some kind of placeholder right now?
>
> A: As you may know, variadic templates
> aren't implemented in VC10. We
> simulate them with preprocessor
> machinery for things like
> `make_shared<T>()`, tuple, and the new
> things in `<functional>`. This
> preprocessor machinery is relatively
> difficult to use and maintain. Also,
> it significantly affects compilation
> speed, as we have to repeatedly
> include subheaders. Due to a
> combination of our time constraints
> and compilation speed concerns, we
> haven't simulated variadic templates
> in our emplace functions.
>
> When variadic templates are
> implemented in the compiler, you can
> expect that we'll take advantage of
> them in the libraries, including in
> our emplace functions. We take
> conformance very seriously, but
> unfortunately, we can't do everything
> all at once.

It's an understandable decision. Everyone who tried just once to emulate variadic template with preprocessor horrible tricks knows how disgusting this stuff gets.

Comment: That clarification that it's a MSVS10 issue, not a C++ issue is the most important part here.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe your last line of C++ code won't work. `pair<const int,Complicated>` does not have a constructor that takes an int, another int, a double and as 4th parameter a string. However, you *can* directly construct this pair object using its piecewise-constructor. The syntax will be different, of course: `m.emplace(std::piecewise,std::forward_as_tuple(4),std::forward_as_tuple(anInt,aDouble,aString));`

Comment: Happily variadic templates will be in VS2013, now in preview.

Comment: should this answer be updated to reflect the new developments in vs2013?

Comment: sorry, but -1 for what @sellibitze said; it was the same compilation error that brought me here looking for help, but all we get is a false statement that the quoted syntax will work (it doesn't). the rest of the text is merely ok. with these 2 things, i dunno why this got upvoted so far.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2013 or later _now_, you should have support for the "real" `emplace_back` so long as it was implemented into Visual C++ when variadic templates were added: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @sellibitze but then you made a mistake while correcting Thomas's mistake... There is no `std::piecewise`; there are only the type `std::piecewise_construct_t` and the global instance thereof `std::piecewise_construct`.

Comment: with gcc 9.2 m.emplace(4, Complicated(anInt, aDouble, aString)) ; works.

Comment: @ThomasPetit , what is this MSCV10

Comment: I think Thomas meant to write, MSVC10 = MicroSoft Visual C++ 10.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop But then you are creating a temporary copy of Complicated, avoiding which is the advantage of emplace_back.

Comment: @Tahlil, I thought that temporary copy would be easily optimized away by the compiler. Is that not so ?

Answer (score 271):

`emplace_back` shouldn't take an argument of type `vector::value_type`, but instead variadic arguments that are forwarded to the constructor of the appended item.

```
template <class... Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args);
```

It is possible to pass a `value_type` which will be forwarded to the copy constructor.

Because it forwards the arguments, this means that if you don't have rvalue, this still means that the container will store a "copied" copy, not a moved copy.

```
 std::vector<std::string> vec;
 vec.emplace_back(std::string("Hello")); // moves
 std::string s;
 vec.emplace_back(s); //copies
```

But the above should be identical to what `push_back` does. It is probably rather meant for use cases like:

```
 std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > vec;
 vec.emplace_back(std::string("Hello"), std::string("world")); 
 // should end up invoking this constructor:
 //template<class U, class V> pair(U&& x, V&& y);
 //without making any copies of the strings
```

Comment: You would need to use vec.emplace_back(std::move(s)); since s is an lvalue to get the move behavior

Comment: @David: but then you have a moved `s` in scope, isn't that dangerous ?

Comment: It's not dangerous if you don't plan on using s any longer for its value. Moving does not make s invalid, the move will only steal the internal memory allocation already done in s and leave it in a defaulted state (no sting allocated) which when destructed will be fine as if you had just typed std::string str;

Comment: @David: I'm not sure that a moved-from object is required to be valid for any use except subsequent destruction.

Comment: `vec.emplace_back("Hello")` will work, since the `const char*` argument will be *forwarded* to the `string` constructor. This is the whole point of `emplace_back`.

Comment: visitor, you are dead wrong, please read Alexandre C. comment and Thomas answer

Comment: `vec.emplace_back(std::string("Hello"))` will also prevent the default string constructor from being called.

Comment: @BenVoigt: A moved-from object is required to be in a valid (but unspecified) state. This doesn't necessarily mean you can perform any operation on it, however. Consider `std::vector`. An empty `std::vector` is a valid state, but you cannot call `front()` on it. This means that any function that has no preconditions can still be called (and destructors can never have preconditions).

Comment: why spend 2/3rds of the answer dwelling on the extremely mundane 'emplace is bad for use-cases that aren't the ones for which it was designed', relegating the actual rationale to a "probably" afterthought?

Answer (score 149):

Optimization for `emplace_back` can be demonstrated in following example.

For `emplace_back`, constructor `A (int x_arg)` will be called.

For `push_back`, `A (int x_arg)` is called first and `move A (A &&rhs)` is called afterward.

Of course, the constructor has to be marked as `explicit`, but for the current example, it is good to remove explicitness.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class A
{
public:
  A (int x_arg) : x (x_arg) { std::cout << "A (x_arg)\n"; }
  A () { x = 0; std::cout << "A ()\n"; }
  A (const A &rhs) noexcept { x = rhs.x; std::cout << "A (A &)\n"; }
  A (A &&rhs) noexcept { x = rhs.x; std::cout << "A (A &&)\n"; }

private:
  int x;
};

int main ()
{
  {
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::cout << "call emplace_back:\n";
    a.emplace_back (0);
  }
  {
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::cout << "call push_back:\n";
    a.push_back (1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
call emplace_back:
A (x_arg)

call push_back:
A (x_arg)
A (A &&)
```

Comment: I came here after noticing that I had code that was calling `v.emplace_back(x);` where x is explicitly move-constructable but only explicitly copy-constructable. The fact that `emplace_back` is "implicitly" explicit makes me think that my go-to function for appending should probably be `push_back`. Thoughts?

Comment: If you call `a.emplace_back` second time, the move constructor will be called!

Comment: @AndreasK. That's not related to emplace_back but rather expanding the size of the vector. You can check that by printing what is being moved rather than just `"A (A &&)\n"`, print `"A (A &&) on " << rhs.x << "\n"`.

You can see it [in this edited code snippet](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/FSiSqRh).

Answer (score 29):

Specific use case for `emplace_back`: If you need to create a temporary object which will then be pushed into a container, use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`. It will create the object in-place within the container.

Notes:

1. `push_back` in the above case will create a temporary object and move it
   into the container. However, in-place construction used for `emplace_back` would be more
   performant than constructing and then moving the object (which generally involves some copying).
2. In general, you can use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` in all the cases without much issue. (See [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919571/1866301))

Answer (score 25):

One more example for lists:

```
// constructs the elements in place.                                                
emplace_back("element");

// creates a new object and then copies (or moves) that object.
push_back(ExplicitDataType{"element"});
```

Comment: does it mean emplace_back does not create a copy ?
It just stores the actual object.
if we change the object itself after emplace_back , the object in vector should also change ,right?

Comment: @MrNobody with `emplace_back` it is the container that forwards the arguments to the constructor - aka neither before nor after that call do you have any object at hand.
what do you mean by "change the object itself"? There is ONLY the object in the container.
Or you create the object beforehand - in which case it acts the same as push_back.

Comment: @MrNobody In order to see the effect you mention, the object that is emplace_back'd into the vector has to have an identity, in which case the object would have been copied rather than being directly inserted into the vector. See visitor's example.

Answer (score 13):

A nice code for the push_back and emplace_back is shown here.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

You can see the move operation on push_back and not on emplace_back.

Answer (score 9):

`emplace_back` conforming implementation will forward arguments to the `vector<Object>::value_type`constructor when added to the vector. I recall Visual Studio didn't support variadic templates, but with variadic templates will be supported in Visual Studio 2013 RC, so I guess a conforming signature will be added.

With `emplace_back`, if you forward the arguments directly to `vector<Object>::value_type` constructor, you don't need a type to be movable or copyable for `emplace_back` function, strictly speaking. In the `vector<NonCopyableNonMovableObject>` case, this is not useful, since `vector<Object>::value_type`  needs a copyable or movable type to grow.

But *note* that this could be useful for `std::map<Key, NonCopyableNonMovableObject>`, since once you allocate an entry in the map, it doesn't need to be moved or copied ever anymore, unlike with `vector`, meaning that you can use `std::map` effectively with a mapped type that is neither copyable nor movable.