# What is multimap::emplace() and move()?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, multimap, rvalue-reference

I was viewing the MSDN doc about multimap and find that it has a member function multimap::emplace(). Below is the example of that member function.

```
int main( ) {
   using namespace std;
   multimap<int, string> m1;
   pair<int, string> is1(1, "a");

   m1.emplace(move(is1));
}
```

It seems that `emplace()` and `move()` are C++0x. Can someone explain them for me? I read about `move()`, but I really don't understand what does it do (under the hood).

Comment: I recommend you to read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Emplacing is easier to understand with vectors. `my_vector.emplace_back(1, 2, 3)` is basically an efficient shortcut for `my_vector.push_back(some_type(1, 2, 3))`. Instead of copy-constructing the object in-place, *any* constructor can now be used for in-place-construction, thus saving the creation, copy (or move) and destruction of a temporary object. Emplacing is powered by *perfect forwarding*.

`std::move(expression)` is basically a cast to an [xvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/), which effectively allows the entire expression to be bound to an rvalue reference. You typically do this to enable resource pilfering from named objects that you are no longer interested in because they are going to be destroyed soon, anyway.

Comment: I belive, that instead `my_vector.emplace(1, 2, 3)` should be `my_vector.emplace_back(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer, which at the very least is inaccurate and arguably wrong.

Comment: So isn't there a typo in msdn doc? I would think that a more explicit example to explain emplace would be `m1.emplace(1, "a")`, i.e. `emplace` forwards the arguments. It seems to me that their example would compile as well with `insert` instead of `emplace`.