# Why couldn't push_back be overloaded to do the job of emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11

Firstly, I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back), but I don't believe I'm asking the same thing.

I know what `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` *does* - and I understand why I would use it over `push_back()`.  It uses variadic templates allowing me to forward multiple arguments to the constructor of a new element.

But what I don't understand is why the C++ standard committee decided there was a need for a new member function.  Why couldn't they simply extend the functionality of `push_back()`.  As far as I can see, `push_back` could be overloaded in C++11 to be:

```
template <class... Args>
void push_back(Args&&... args);
```

This would not break backwards compatibility, while allowing you to pass N arguments, including arguments that would invoke a normal rvalue or copy constructor.  In fact, the GCC C++11 implementation of `push_back()` simply calls emplace_back anyway:

```
  void push_back(value_type&& __x)
  { 
    emplace_back(std::move(__x)); 
  }
```

So, the way I see it, there is no need for `emplace_back()`.  All they needed to add was an overload for `push_back()` which accepts variadic arguments, and forwards the arguments to the element constructor.

Am I wrong here?  Is there some reason that an entirely new function was needed here?

Comment: this looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

Comment: Good question. @moka he knows the difference between what the two functions do. He even linked to that particular question.

Comment: They have different meanings, it's all explained in the question you mentioned you read. Compare `v.emplace_back(123)` and `v.push_back(123)` for example for `vector<SomeType> v;` with implicit conversion from `int`.

Comment: @Gene: Okay, I've compared them, and I don't see what the difference would be if push_back was simply modified to do what emplace_back does.  Would you mind expounding upon it here?

Comment: That's pretty standard practice for library development. You don't change your interface you make a new one. Then allow users to implement the old API in terms of the new API at their own pace while the code never becomes broken.

Comment: @Benjamin -- it's obvious, in one case you move the temporary, in the other you construct an object in place. It's a trivial example for illustration purposes, but it does show the difference.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If T has an explicit conversion constructor, there is different behavior between `emplace_back` and `push_back`.

```
struct X
{
    int val;
    X() :val() {}
    explicit X(int v) :val(v) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> v;
    v.push_back(123);    // this fails
    v.emplace_back(123); // this is okay
}
```

Making the change you suggest would mean that `push_back` would be legal in that instance, and I suppose that was not desired behavior.  I don't know if this is the reason, but it's the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: It is especially useful when handling containers of `unique_ptr`s, since `v.emplace_back(new foo)` is much simpler than `v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo))`. But one should be able to *request explicitly* the conversion in this case.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Actually, `emplace_back(new foo)` is not exception-safe, so it's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Yeah -- specifically the potential allocation required to enlarge the vector. A potential meta-lesson to take away here is: don't use a new feature out of pure laziness in typing when using it is not actually necessary.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Can't tell if you're joking, but you should just use `push_back(make_unique<foo>())` if you're not sticking with the original (which would be fine by me too)...

Comment: @Mehrdad C++ has become a tad verbose lately, hasn't it. Yes, the template was a joke. I fully agree with you, but at the time I wrote that comment, we were using Visual Studio 2010, with no support of `make_unique`, and we still occasionally compile code with it. Nowadays, we grep for `new` and `delete` in our codebase.

Comment: ...and emulate `make_unique` with a dozen templates, all put (disgustingly) under `namespace std` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example.

Honestly, the two are semantically *so* different, that their similar behavior should be regarded as a mere *coincidence* (due to the fact that C++ has "copy constructors" with a particular syntax).

You should really *not* use `emplace_back` unless you want *in-place-construction* semantics.
It's rare that you'd need such a thing. Generally `push_back` is what you really, semantically want.

```
#include <vector>

struct X { X(struct Y const &); };
struct Y { Y(int const &); operator X(); };

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> v;
    v.   push_back(Y(123));  // Calls Y::operator X() and Y::Y(int const &)
    v.emplace_back(Y(123));  // Calls X::X(Y const &) and Y::Y(int const &)
}
```