# how to move an std::unique_ptr<> from one STL container to another?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

#### Problem

I have a template container `MyContainer<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` which has a `std::deque<T>` and a `std::vector<T>` member.

Inside method, `send_to_purgatory_if( predicate )`, I would like to look at all items in `m_taskdq` and move items from `m_taskdq` to `m_purgatory`, if the predicate evaluates to true.

#### Issues

I have two issues that I'm struggling with:

- my iterator **`it`** gets trashed if I remove items from m_taskdq from inside the loop
- I am worried about the state of the `std::unique_ptr<>` if I do the move in two steps (problem lines 1 and 2 - by line 2, I think the `std::unique_ptr<>` pointed to by **`it`** is undefined?)

**How should I fix this code?**

```
    template <typename T>
    class MyContainer
    {
      typedef std::function<bool(T&)>  PREDICATE;
    
      void send_to_purgatory_if( PREDICATE p )
      {
// bad code -------------------------------------
        for( auto it=m_taskdq.begin(); it!=m_taskdq.end(); ++it )
        {
          if ( p( *it ) )
          {
            m_purgatory.emplace_back( move( *it ));  // problem line 1
            m_taskdq.erase( it );                    // problem line 2
          }
        }
// end bad code ---------------------------------
      }
    
      std::deque<  T >  m_taskdq;                                                     
      std::vector< T >  m_purgatory;
    };
```

Comment: Why using emplace_back ? Appending an item to a container by moving it is a job for push_back(value_type&&). emplace_back(args&&...) primary point is to forward arguments and construct directly into a container by using an already existing constructor. It's true that emplace_back decays to push_back if only one argument is used but that's really unfortunate IMHO and leads only to confusion. More info here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back/4306581#4306581 with my answer and also the comment by lurscher

Comment: @ThomasPetit Because I am moving an std::unique_ptr<> from one container to another (as described in detail above)?  Are you telling me that in my case, I can/should use push_back() instead?

Comment: The next question we need to ask if the erase method sends the task to heaven or hell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is really a C++98 question, with a red-herring concerning move semantics.  The first thing to ask is how to do this in C++98:

`std::deque::erase(iterator)` returns an `iterator` that refers to the element after the one erased.  So get that working first:

```
 void send_to_purgatory_if( PREDICATE p )
  {
    for( auto it=m_taskdq.begin(); it!=m_taskdq.end();)
    {
      if ( p( *it ) )
      {
        m_purgatory.emplace_back(*it);
        it = m_taskdq.erase(it);
      }
      else
        ++it;
    }
  }
```

And now it is easy to make it work with C++11 move semantics:

```
 void send_to_purgatory_if( PREDICATE p )
  {
    for( auto it=m_taskdq.begin(); it!=m_taskdq.end();)
    {
      if ( p( *it ) )
      {
        m_purgatory.emplace_back(std::move(*it));
        it = m_taskdq.erase(it);
      }
      else
        ++it;
    }
  }
```

The `unique_ptr` moved from in `taskdq` becomes a null `unique_ptr` after the `emplace_back`, and then it gets erased in the next line.  No harm, no foul.

When there is an `erase`, the return from the `erase` does a good job at incrementing the iterator.  And when there is no `erase`, a normal iterator increment is in order.

Comment: +1 tyvm for a fantastic breakdown of the problem - trying it out now