# create a dynamic array while delaying object construction

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'd like to be able to "somehow" create a dynamic array that would still let me build its elements using the new operator.
Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
A* a = new A[3]; //or any equivalent syntax 
new (&a[0]) A(myparams1); //placement new on first slot 
new (&a[1]) A(myparams2, ...); //placement new on 2nd slot 
new (&a[2]) A(myparams3, ...); //placement new on 3rd slot
delete[] a; //correct deletion of all elements
```

I'm aware  that this code would work (minus the 3 elements overwritten), but I'd like to avoid creating 3 default `a` elements in the first call to `new[]`. I am assuming here that I will *always* place 3 elements before calling `delete[]`.
I'm thinking such a thing can be achieved by using intelligent calls to `A::operator new[]` but I'm not sure how.
Does anyone have any idea? it's mostly for curiosity

Comment: and which parts of std::vector don't you like?

Comment: You have syntax error in the first line, probably should be `A * a`.

Comment: Also see here how a C++11 vector will do all this for you with `emplace_back` [push_back vs emplace_back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just get raw memory instead:

```
void* mem = ::operator new(capacity * sizeof(A));
```

This is required to be aligned for any type, including an array of `A`'s. Now you can construct in it:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
{
    void* addr = static_cast<char*>(mem) + i * sizeof(A);
    new (addr) A(x, y, z, ...);
}
```

Destruction requires you explicitly invoke it:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
{
    void* addr = static_cast<char*>(mem) + i * sizeof(A);
    static_cast<A*>(addr)->~A();
}
```

And now you can free the raw memory:

```
::operator delete(mem);
```

Note that none of this is exception-safe. It's also what `std::vector<A>` does, check out the code.

Comment: thanks, this looks fine indeed.
I'm just wondering if there isn't a variant for arrays? I'm thinking this would be the perfect time to use ::operator new[] and ::operator delete[]

Comment: @lezebulon: If you want a chunk of `x` bytes, you should just use `::operator new` (or kin). If you want `x` bytes *in an array*, then sure, use `::operator new[]`. But note that's not what we want here, the array is just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what would using ::operator new[] change? I'd be tempted to use it since I'm allocating for an array of objects

Comment: @lezebulon: You can use it just fine, it just doesn't match conceptually. You *are not* allocating an array during that `::operator new` call, you're allocating a chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use operator new.

```
A a* = (A*) ::operator new(sizeof(A) * 3);
new (&a[0]) A(/* whatever */);
//do stuff
a[0].~A();
::operator delete(a);
```

Pay careful attention to manually calling the destructors.  When using placement new the destructor is not called automagically so it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of pointers.

```
A ** a = new A*[3]
a[0] = new A;
a[1] = new A;
a[2] = new A;
```

You need to call `delete` on each allocated element

```
delete a[2];
delete a[1];
delete a[0];
```

And to delete array itself `delete[] a;`