# Why would I ever use push_back instead of emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

C++11 vectors have the new function `emplace_back`. Unlike `push_back`, which relies on compiler optimizations to avoid copies, `emplace_back` uses perfect forwarding to send the arguments directly to the constructor to create an object in-place. It seems to me that `emplace_back` does everything `push_back` can do, but some of the time it will do it better (but never worse).

What reason do I have to use `push_back`?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

I have thought about this question quite a bit over the past four years. I have come to the conclusion that most explanations about `push_back` vs. `emplace_back` miss the full picture.

Last year, I gave a presentation at C++Now on [Type Deduction in C++14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_utkragEjRA). I start talking about `push_back` vs. `emplace_back` at 13:49, but there is useful information that provides some supporting evidence prior to that.

The real primary difference has to do with implicit vs. explicit constructors. Consider the case where we have a single argument that we want to pass to `push_back` or `emplace_back`.

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.push_back(x);
v.emplace_back(x);
```

After your optimizing compiler gets its hands on this, there is no difference between these two statements in terms of generated code. The traditional wisdom is that `push_back` will construct a temporary object, which will then get moved into `v` whereas `emplace_back` will forward the argument along and construct it directly in place with no copies or moves. This may be true based on the code as written in standard libraries, but it makes the mistaken assumption that the optimizing compiler's job is to generate the code you wrote. The optimizing compiler's job is actually to generate the code you would have written if you were an expert on platform-specific optimizations and did not care about maintainability, just performance.

The actual difference between these two statements is that the more powerful `emplace_back` will call any type of constructor out there, whereas the more cautious `push_back` will call only constructors that are implicit. Implicit constructors are supposed to be safe. If you can implicitly construct a `U` from a `T`, you are saying that `U` can hold all of the information in `T` with no loss. It is safe in pretty much any situation to pass a `T` and no one will mind if you make it a `U` instead. A good example of an implicit constructor is the conversion from `std::uint32_t` to `std::uint64_t`. A bad example of an implicit conversion is `double` to `std::uint8_t`.

We want to be cautious in our programming. We do not want to use powerful features because the more powerful the feature, the easier it is to accidentally do something incorrect or unexpected. If you intend to call explicit constructors, then you need the power of `emplace_back`. If you want to call only implicit constructors, stick with the safety of `push_back`.

**An example**

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> v;
T a;
v.emplace_back(std::addressof(a)); // compiles
v.push_back(std::addressof(a)); // fails to compile
```

`std::unique_ptr<T>` has an explicit constructor from `T *`. Because `emplace_back` can call explicit constructors, passing a non-owning pointer compiles just fine. However, when `v` goes out of scope, the destructor will attempt to call `delete` on that pointer, which was not allocated by `new` because it is just a stack object. This leads to undefined behavior.

This is not just invented code. This was a real production bug I encountered. The code was `std::vector<T *>`, but it owned the contents. As part of the migration to C++11, I correctly changed `T *` to `std::unique_ptr<T>` to indicate that the vector owned its memory. However, I was basing these changes off my understanding in 2012, during which I thought "`emplace_back` does everything `push_back` can do and more, so why would I ever use `push_back`?", so I also changed the `push_back` to `emplace_back`.

Had I instead left the code as using the safer `push_back`, I would have instantly caught this long-standing bug and it would have been viewed as a success of upgrading to C++11. Instead, I masked the bug and didn't find it until months later.

Comment: It would help if you could elaborate on what exactly emplace does in your example, and why it's wrong.

Comment: @eddi: I added a section explaining this: `std::unique_ptr<T>` has an explicit constructor from `T *`. Because `emplace_back` can call explicit constructors, passing a non-owning pointer compiles just fine. However, when `v` goes out of scope, the destructor will attempt to call `delete` on that pointer, which was not allocated by `new` because it is just a stack object. This leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I didn't know about it when I wrote my answer but now I wish I'd written it myself when I did learn it afterward :) I really want to slap people who switch to new features just to do the hippest thing they can find. Guys, people were using C++ before C++11 too, and not *everything* about it was problematic. *If you don't know why you're using a feature, **don't use it***. So glad you posted this and I hope it gets way more upvotes so it goes above mine. +1

Comment: @DavidStone Did you mean to say 'implicit' instead of 'explicit' in your answer?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow: It looks like I say implicit and explicit where I mean them. Which part has you confused?

Comment: @DavidStone Doesn't this statement :"`std::unique_ptr<T>` has an explicit constructor from `T *`" mean that the programmer actually wrote that constructor. But I thought you wanted to imply the constructor that is automatically provided by the language or generated by the compiler (implicit).

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow: An `explicit` constructor is a constructor that has the keyword `explicit` applied to it. An "implicit" constructor is any constructor that does not have that keyword. In the case of `std::unique_ptr`'s constructor from `T *`, the implementor of `std::unique_ptr` wrote that constructor, but the issue here is that the user of that type called `emplace_back`, which called that explicit constructor. If it had been `push_back`, instead of calling that constructor, it would have relied on an implicit conversion, which can only call implicit constructors.

Comment: Excellent answer. For what it’s worth, Abseil’s [Tip of the week #112](https://abseil.io/tips/112) argues much the same.

Comment: @DavidStone, you said, regarding your pre-C++11 code: "The code was `std::vector<T *>`, but it owned the contents." That isn't true, right? I mean, the variable `a` is on the stack, so the vector obviously doesn't own its lifetime.

Comment: @DavidStone, the mistake that we do with emplace_back can happen even with push_back thus:

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> v;`
`T a;`
`std::unique_ptr<T> p(std::addressof(a));`
`v.push_back(std::move(p));`

Right? Here too, we've ended up putting a stack variable into a unique_ptr

Comment: Yes, it's possible to intentionally do this. But with the old code it happened accidentally (the `vector` was supposed to own dynamic memory but someone put the address of a stack variable in there thinking it was just normal pointers). For your code to happen accidentally, someone would have to have a function that accepts a raw pointer and then someone puts that pointer in a `unique_ptr` -- `vector` has nothing to do with the bug in the example you gave.

Answer (score 131):

`push_back` always allows the use of uniform initialization, which I'm very fond of. For instance:

```
struct aggregate {
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

std::vector<aggregate> v;
v.push_back({ 42, 121 });
```

On the other hand, `v.emplace_back({ 42, 121 });` will not work.

Comment: Note that this only applies to aggregate initialization and initializer-list initialization. If you would be using `{}` syntax to call an actual constructor, then you can just remove the `{}`'s and use `emplace_back`.

Comment: Dumb question time: so emplace_back can't be used for vectors of structs at all? Or just not for this style using literal {42,121}?

Comment: @LucDanton: As I said, it only applies to *aggregate* and *initializer-list* initialization. You can use `{}` syntax to call actual constructors. You could give `aggregate` a constructor that takes 2 integers, and this constructor would be called when using `{}` syntax. The point being that if you're *trying* to call a constructor, `emplace_back` would be preferable, since it calls the constructor in-place. And therefore doesn't require the type to be copyable.

Comment: Why `std::initializer_list<int>`? I do not think that `emplace_back({ anything here })` ever works.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah, I got confused by your use of "this only applies": what does *this* refer to? (Similarly what's "it" in "it only applies"?) What I value in `push_back` is not that it's *possible* to use uniform initialization for some cases, it's that it's reliable whether e.g. the value type is an aggregate or not, as you mention.

Comment: Fixed some confusion regarding passing `{ a, b, c }` to function templates.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't think `push_back` requires the type to be copyable in C++11, does it?

Comment: std::tuple would allow use of emplace_back in this case

Comment: @NicolBolas So the only reason to ever use push_back is "aggregate initialization and initializer-list initialization"? Since that's not exactly the same as "uniform initialization", shouldn't this answer be modified?

Comment: This was viewed as a defect in the standard, and has been resolved. See https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2089

Comment: @DavidStone Had it been resolved, it wouldn't still be in the "active" list... no? It appears to remain an outstanding issue. The latest update, headed "_[2018-08-23 Batavia Issues processing]_", says that "_[P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0960r1.html) (currently in flight) should resolve this._" And I still can't compile code that tries to `emplace` aggregates without explicitly writing a boilerplate constructor. It's also unclear at this point whether it'll be treated as a defect and thus eligible for backporting, or whether users of C++ < 20 will remain SoL.

Comment: @underscore_d: Excellent point. I had misunderstood the status of the issue when I had posted that comment. Instead, this has been resolved in C++20 by http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html, which was voted into the standard.

Comment: I am curious how does the object gets constructed here. There is no deafult constructor with 2 arguments. So, how does it actually construct the object based on `{42,21}`

Answer (score 84):

Backwards compatibility with pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: That seems to be the curse of C++. We get tons of cool features with each new release, but a lot of companies are either stuck using some old version for the sake of compatibility or discouraging (if not disallowing) use of certain features.

Comment: @DanAlbert: Not sure why it's a curse. Why use a new feature when the old one is sufficient?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why settle for sufficient when you can have great? I sure wouldn't want to be programming in [blub](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html), even if it was sufficient. Not saying that's the case for this example in particular, but as someone who spends most of his time programming in C89 for the sake of compatibility, it's definitely a real problem.

Comment: @DanAlbert: I wasn't making a general statement, I was just talking about `push_back` lol.

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer to the question. To me he's asking for use-cases where `push_back` is preferable.

Comment: @Mr.Boy: It's preferable when you want to be backward-compatible with pre-C++11 compilers. Was that unclear in my answer?

Comment: This has gotten way more attention than I've expected, so for all of you reading this: `emplace_back` is **not** a "great" version of `push_back`. It's a potentially **dangerous** version of it. *Read the other answers.*

Comment: @user541686, you should add this last comment of yours to the answer itself, as it's important. Also, there are many other answers, so just saying "_read the other answers_" is insufficient. Please quote a couple other answers which you find most pertinent, and link to them.

Answer (score 74):

Some library implementations of emplace_back do not behave as specified in the C++ standard including the version that ship with Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and 2015.

In order to accommodate known compiler bugs, prefer using`std::vector::push_back()` if the parameters reference iterators or other objects which will be invalid after the call.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.emplace_back(123);
v.emplace_back(v[0]); // Produces incorrect results in some compilers
```

On one compiler, v contains the values 123 and 21 instead of the expected 123 and 123. This is due to the fact that the 2nd call to `emplace_back` results in a resize at which point `v[0]` becomes invalid.

A working implementation of the above code would use `push_back()` instead of `emplace_back()` as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.emplace_back(123);
v.push_back(v[0]);
```

Note: The use of a vector of ints is for demonstration purposes. I discovered this issue with a much more complex class which included dynamically allocated member variables and the call to `emplace_back()` resulted in a hard crash.

Comment: Wait. This appears to be a bug. How can `push_back` be different in this case?

Comment: The call to emplace_back() uses perfect forwarding to perform construction in place and as such v[0] is not evaluated until after the vector has been resized (at which point v[0] is invalid). push_back constructs the new element and copies/moves the element as needed and v[0] is evaluated prior to any reallocation.

Comment: Can you give an example of a compiler where you see this behaviour? I can't reproduce this problem. I suspect what you actually saw is the reference to v[0] being invalidated when the vector reallocated.

Comment: @cdyson37 The described behavior was observed using Visual Studio 2012 compiler version 11 update 4.

Comment: @David - Although the new space must exist before the old is destroyed, I don't think that there are any guarantees regarding when the parameter of emplace_back is evaluated. Perfect forwarding enables delayed evaluation. It is my observation that the old vector iterators become invalid before the parameter is evaluated in the compile on which I tested and the details are largely implementation dependent.

Comment: @Marc: It is guaranteed by the standard that emplace_back works even for elements inside the range.

Comment: @Marc why v[0] is not evaluated until after the vector has been resized? could you describe it in detail?

Comment: @DavidStone: Could please provide a reference to where in the standard this behavior is guaranteed? Either way, Visual Studio 2012 and 2015 exhibit incorrect behavior.

Comment: @cameino: emplace_back exists to delay evaluation of its parameter to reduce unnecessary copying. The behavior is either undefined or a compiler bug (pending analysis of the standard). I recently ran the same test against Visual Studio 2015 and got 123,3 under Release x64, 123,40 under Release Win32 and 123,-572662307 under Debug x64 and Debug Win32.

Comment: The standard guarantee is found at http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:container.seq.opt. The guarantee isn't specifically stated as such, but rather, when the standard describes the behavior it does not include a precondition that the object not already be in the container, therefore the implementations are required to make this work. It's unfortunate that Visual Studio has a bug in this. :(

Comment: @DavidStone: it doesn't seem practical to expect the Standard to guarantee this would work.  More generally, the problem exists whenever `emplace_back` is passed a reference to anything inside the existing container, however indirectly (it might not come from the function calling `emplace_back`): that wouldn't necessarily be able to detected at compile time, and to check for it at runtime would be unwanted overhead on all `emplace_back` calls.  It makes sense that this is - and is left as - undefined behaviour.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: It is not undefined behavior, the standard does guarantee it. There is also no overhead from supporting this (which is the reason it wasn't carved out as being undefined behavior). If you don't need to reallocate, there's no issue because old references are valid. If you do need to reallocate, you allocate the new storage, construct the new object in the correct location in that storage, then move the old objects over. All of that is work you have do regardless, so there's no extra cost.

Comment: @DavidStone: oh yeah, that does make sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens in Visual Studio 2019 with c++-17 compiler. We have emplace_back in a function with proper arguments set up. Then someone changes parameters of the constuctor called by emplace_back. There is no warning whatsover in VS, the code also compiles fine, then it crashes in runtime. I removed all emplace_back from the codebase after this.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Use `push_back` only for primitive/built-in types or raw pointers. Otherwise use `emplace_back`.