# vector push_back with forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I do something like this in my code

```
S s;
s.a=1
s.b=2
v.push_back(s)
```

Now that C++ has forwarding can i write something like

```
v.push_back(1,2)
```

fyi visual studio supports forwarding as the below works as expected

```
//http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::vector::emplace_back` which will create the object inplace with the fitting constructor. This of course requires that you have such a constructor defined.

```
v.emplace_back(1,2);
```

As of C++11 every std-container offers an emplace-like function which gives the above described behavior.

Compatibility-note: MSVC probably doesn't support this yet as it only supports variadic templates as of the CTP which doesn't affect the standard library and gcc's libstd++ is still missing the emplace member functions in the associative containers.

Answer (score 2):

`push_back` doesn't support forwarding, but the new `emplace_back` does.

However, `push_back` does support initializer lists:

```
v.push_back({1,2});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Do any compilers support this syntax yet? It looks like `{}` isnt supported by MSVC yet

Comment: Try the example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10890716/1204143 and see if it will compile. (If not, then MSVC is not yet C++11 compliant and you will have to use `emplace_back`).

Comment: it doesnt. Does GCC support that? I dont have it installed or maybe i have an old version

Comment: Works on my version of Clang, so I suspect this is just an unimplemented feature in MSVC.