# Emplace_back instead of push_back on stl containers?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm not quite sure if i can always replace `push_back` with `emplace_back`.

I know `emplace_back` can forward the parameters to construct the object directly in the vector without copying twice (perfect forwarding etc...)

And if i do soemthing like this:

```
vector<A> o;
o.emplace_back(A{});
```

Then it should call the copy constructor of A. Correct ?
So it does exactly the same as `push_back`. Doesn't it ?

Are there some exceptions?
Are there good reasons to use push_back ? Because then it is easier to just use always emplace_back without thinking about it.

Comment: What's your question? If you wanted to take advantage of emplacing, you'd write `o.emplace_back();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I replace all calls to push\_back with emplace\_back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468837/should-i-replace-all-calls-to-push-back-with-emplace-back)

Comment: After c++11 there's `push_back(value_type&& val)` so there's no need for `emplace_back` temporary `A{}`.

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose of `emplace` is to perform *explicit conversions*:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::vector<std::chrono::seconds> time;

time.push_back(1s);     // OK
// time.push_back(1);   // Error, thank god
time.emplace_back(1);   // OK, we assume you know what you're doing
```

Use `push_back` to add an element of a given value to the container. Use `emplace_back` to explicitly construct an element from constructor arguments.

Comment: Another important feature of `emplace_back`is, from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back , *typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container.*

Comment: @RSahu: Well, yes, that's what emplacing *does*, but that doesn't answer why you would want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Another application (besides the answer of [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30942778/2249683)) for 'emplace_back' is constructing a non-copyable/non-movable object in a container:

```
#include <list>

class Resource
{
    private:
    int id;
    int data;

    public:
    Resource(int id, int data) : id(id), data(data) {}
    Resource(const Resource&) = delete;
    Resource& operator = (const Resource&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::list<Resource> resources;
    // The following will not compile:
    // resources.push_back(Resource(1, 2));
    resources.emplace_back(1, 2);
}
```