# Do the new C++11 emplace methods make the previous C++98/03 push_back/insert methods obsolete?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, stl

Does it still make sense in C++11 to use `vector::push_back()` instead of `vector::emplace_back()`, and similarly `map::insert()` instead of `map::emplace()`?

My understanding is that the new modern C++11 *emplace*-methods construct objects *in place* with the given arguments (perfectly forwarded to constructors), so they save copy and move operations, so they should be more efficient than their old C++98/03 counterparts.

Am I missing something about that?

Is it safe to discourage the use of the old-style methods?

Comment: Sound about right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890653/why-would-i-ever-use-push-back-instead-of-emplace-back

Comment: If you need backwards compatibility?

Comment: emplace_back() will call constructors, push_back() will invoke copy or move for existing object.

Comment: @chris: According to the thread you linked (thanks), it seems that the only reason to use `vector::push_back` instead of `emplace_back` is being able to use uniform initialization. Is my understanding correct? Anyway, from a perf perspective, `emplace_back` should be better, right?

Comment: @RedX: If it's only for backwards compatibility, then can they be discouraged for new code?

Comment: @berkus: Do you mean: "if you already have an object created elsewhere, use push_back; else, if you are creating the object just to put it into vector, use emplace_back"? Thanks.

Comment: BTW: If you guys write your notes as answers instead of comments, I'd be happy to give proper credit upvoting them.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The signature of push_back accepts either a const reference or refref to your already existing object. emplace_back accepts only arguments to the constructor for given type.

Answer (score 2):

From the difference in signatures of push_back() and emplace_back() it's easy to see that push_back will work with already made object (a temporary if you create it at the call site or implicitly), while emplace_back() will construct an object from passed arguments in place using perfect forwarding.

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T&& value );
```

vs

```
template< class... Args >
void emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

Code sample

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1); // "Constructs" an int object in place, then passes it by reference or refref
v.emplace_back(1); // Calls int constructor with argument 1 directly in place in vector


vector<SpaceShip> u;
u.push_back(SpaceShip(new Engine(), new Hull())); // Make a temporary, then COPY or MOVE
u.emplace_back(new Engine(), new Hull()); // Construct in place
```

Comment: I'd consider differences for objects bigger and more complex than simple integers :)

Comment: Well, int is just an example. Of course a complex object would have more overhead and be more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `emplace_back` is meant to *construct objects*. So what if you already have an object and you want to copy or move it inside the container? Why should you call `emplace_back` to create a *new* instance, even if you can move your existing object into this new instance?

Both alternatives can be useful, for different purposes. `emplace_back` might be able to do exactly the same with `push_back` with the same performance, but it's still cleaner to show your intent in your code.