# Guaranteed copy elision in C++17 and emplace_back(...)

Tags: c++, c++17

[emplace_back(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) was introduced with C++11 to prevent the creation of temporary objects. Now with C++17 pure lvalues are even purer so that they do not lead to the creation of temporaries anymore (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work) for more). Now I still do not fully understand the consequences of these changes, do we still need `emplace_back(...)` or can we just go back and use `push_back(...)` again?

Comment: Perhaps you mean pure rvalues? Argument of `push_back` won't be a pure rvalue or even a normal rvalue (without an extra cast). So if you constructing a new value then it would be better to use `emplace_back`

Comment: emplace_back gives you additional functionality over push_back, it allows you to directly specify arguments which are passed to constructor.

Comment: Copy elision is for return values...

Comment: @Aconcagua Isn't copy elision for passing parameters by value as well? For return values, it's a specific case named _(named) return value optimization_.

Comment: `push_back` accepts only a single argument. Therefore, if you need to pass multiple arguments to the constructor of an inserted element, then with `push_back`, you need to manually write its type. Such as `v.push_back(std::string(10,'x'));` instead of `v.emplace_back(10,'x');`.

Comment: From the first glance, `emplace_back` seems to be the superior alternative compared to `push_back`. Everything you can do with `push_back` can also be achieved with `emplace_back` and additionally, `emplace_back` allows you to forward arbitrary many arguments to the constructor. However, there is a difference when it comes to implicit vs explicit constructors. This answer explains it quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919571/6095394

Comment: @DanielLangr Copy elision is the more general term and is the way (N)RVO is implemented. The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision) lists the situations when copy elision is allowed, among which function parameters are not (exept for co-routines). For parameters, there are already means to avoid copies (references; I suppose this is the reason for the standard not allowing copy elisions on parameters...), but these are not available for return values.

Comment: @Aconcagua Not only for return values. See here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html "when a temporary object is used to initialize another object (including the object returned by a function, or the exception object created by a throw-expression)"

Comment: @Nils You haven't peaked into the link I provided, have you?

Comment: @Aconcagua As far as I understand it: This is not really copy elision (but unfortunately called so) bc according to C++17 prvalues do not require the creation of a temporary (that can be elided later). So no temporary, no elision!

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right that the paragraph you linked changed in C++17. In C++11/14, there was an additional case that might apply to initialization of parameters as well. That's what I meant, but this question is about C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see here: [std::vector::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) that this method requires either CopyInsertable or MoveInsertable, also it takes either `const T& value` or `T&& value`, so I dont see how elision could be of use here.

The new rules of mandatory copy ellision are of use in the following example:

```
struct Data {
    Data() {}
    Data(const Data&) = delete;
    Data(Data&&) = delete;
};

Data create() {
    return Data{};  // error before c++17   
}

void foo(Data) {}

int main()
{
    Data pf = create();
    foo(Data{});  // error before c++17
}
```

so, you have a class which does not support copy/move operations. Why, because maybe its too expensive. Above example is a kind of a factory method which always works. With new rules you dont need to worry if compiler will actually use elision - even if your class supports copy/move.

I dont see the new rules will make push_back faster. emplace_back is still more efficient but not because of the copy ellision but because of the fact it creates object in place with forwarding arguments to it.

Comment: "emplace_back is still more efficient but not because of the copy ellision but because of the fact it creates object in place with forwarding arguments to it." That is what I do not get: If no temporary is created what is then the difference to creating the object in-place?

Comment: @Nils std::vector have some capacity - which means it have more memory allocated than it requires currently, when you emplace_back to it, then std::vector will use `placement new` which constructs object in already allocated memory. With c++11 you are allowed to forward arguments which in the end allows library creators to implement emplace_back.  So when you emplace_back - only constructor is being called (assuming capacity is enough) and maybe arguments might get copied/moved. But I wonder if such arguments might take benefit of mandatory elision since c++17.

Comment: If you push_back(MyNonMovableType()) does guaranteed copy elision not apply here? Isn't MyNonMovableType() a prvalue?

Comment: No, it will ask for a move constructor : https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39af319eafaaefab

Comment: I guess that is because push_back(...) only takes a constant lvalue reference or a rvalue reference. But this works: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edf5552c4944e3a8 So ... if we had `void push_back( T value );` it would work as well!

Comment: Ooooh that will actually make the habit of using const refs to avoid copies obsolete in this cases!

Comment: @marcinj You generally cannot use `std::vector` with a value type that does not support both copy/move construction. Even `reserve` member function requires the value type to be _move-insertable_. (That's, e.g., why you cannot have a vector of atomic ints: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nu3IZWLeInjfZZAg).

Answer (score 2):

Both `push_back` and `emplace_back` member functions create a new object of its `value_type` `T` at some place of the pre-allocated buffer. This is accomplished by the vector's allocator, which, by default, uses the *placement new* mechanism for this construction (placement new is basically just a way of constructing an object at a specified place in memory).

However:

- `emplace_back` perfect-forwards its arguments to the constructor of `T`, thus the constructor that is the best match for these arguments is selected.
- `push_back(T&&)` internally uses the **move constructor** (*if it exists and does not throw*) to initialize the new element. This call of move constructor **cannot be elided** and is always used.

Consider the following situation:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back(std::string("hello"));
```

The `std::string`'s move constructor is always called here that follows the converting constructor which creates a string object from a string literal. In this case:

```
v.emplace_back("hello");
```

there is no move constructor called and the vector's element is initialized by `std::string`'s converting constructor directly.

---

This does not necessarily mean the `push_back` is less efficient. Compiler optimizations might eliminate all the additional instructions and finally both cases might produce the exact same assembly code. Just it's not guaranteed.

---

By the way, if `push_back` passed arguments by value — `void push_back(T param);` — then this would be a case for the application of copy elision. Namely, in:

```
v.push_back(std::string("hello"));
```

the parameter `param` would be constructed by a move-constructor from the temporary. This move-construction would be a candidate for copy elision. However, this approach would not at all change anything about the mandatory move-construction for vector's element inside `push_back` body.