# How to choose between `push_*()` and `emplace_*()` functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, container-data-type

I understand the difference between the two function variants.

My question is: should I normally use good old `push_*()` version and only switch to `emplace_*()` when my profiler tells me this will benefit performance (that is, do not optimise prematurely)? Or should I switch to using `emplace_*()` as the default (perhaps not to pessimise the code unnecessarily - similar to `i++` vs `++i` in `for` loops)?

Is any of the variants more universal than the other (that is, imposes less constraints on the type being inserted) in realistic non-contrived use cases?

Comment: Related and (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/4303513/1870232

Comment: push and emplace are not drop-in substitutes for each other. They do two completely different things. If you fully understand the difference between the two, then you should be able to decide, yourself, which one would be more appropriate in a particular situation. This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with optimization, although the correct choice will, on occasion, have performance differences; but by itself the correct decision would be made for other reasons.

Comment: I always use emplace by default

Comment: It's not like using `emplace` when `push` would do is any *worse*. You might as well get used to writing `emplace` by default.

Comment: It's almost a duplicate, but not quite. Either way, performance isn't the deciding factor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I understand they are not drop-in substitutes. The issue is subtle however. You wrote a lengthy comment, but did not mention any of the reasons to choose one over the other. What those would be? My type can equally well be pushed and emplaced. So shall I push or emplace? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: This question (and answer) explain it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890653/why-would-i-ever-use-push-back-instead-of-emplace-back?noredirect=1&lq=1 In short: Use push_back if you want to call only implicit constructors. Use emplace_back otherwise.

Comment: The reasons to choose one over the other is whether you need to make a copy of an existing object into a vector or construct a brand new object in place. There's nothing "subtle" about the difference. They are two completely different things, as different as night and day.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Considering the issue of implicit and explicit constructors adds some subtlety to the problem, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While writing the code I would not worry about performance. Performance is for later when you already have code that you can profile.

I'd rather worry about expressiveness of the code. Roughly speaking, `push_back` is for when you have an element and want to place a copy inside the container. `emplace_back` is to construct the element in place.

Consider what has the lower "wtf-count":

```
struct foo {int x;int y;};

void foo_add(const foo& f,std::vector<foo>& v) {
    v.emplace_back(f);   // wtf ?!? we already have a foo
    v.push_back(f);      // ... simply make a copy (or move)
}

void foo_add(int x, int y, std::vector<foo>& v) {
    auto z = foo{x,y};      // wtf ?!? 
    f.push_back(z);         // why create a temporary?
    f.emplace_back(x,y);    // ... simply construct it in place
}
```

Comment: The `int` example is not that great imo. Moving, copy-constructing or "emplacing" an int all amount to the same thing. I don't see a `wtf` in either way of appending an `int` here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I think it is little better now

Answer (score 2):

`emplace` functions are delegating constructors.

Let's say you have a container of T.

If you **already have** a T, maybe it's const, maybe it's a rvalue, maybe none of those;
Then you use `push_xxx()`.
Your object will be copied/moved into the container.

If you instead want to **construct** a T, then you use `emplace_xxx()`, with the *same parameters you would send the constructor*.
An object will be constructed directly in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Emplace functions are more generic than push functions. In no case they are less efficient, on the contrary - they can be more efficient, as they allow to optimize away one copy/move operation of the container element when you need to construct it from arguments. When putting an element into container involves copy/move anyway, emplace and push operations are equivalent.

Push can be preferable, if you actually want to enforce construction before copying/moving the element into the container. For example, if your element type has some special logic in its constructor that you want to execute before the container is modified. Such cases are quite rare, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from `push_back` to `emplace_back` in a naive way, you will have no advantage at all. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct President
{
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int year;

    President(std::string p_name, std::string p_country, int p_year) :
            name(std::move(p_name)), country(std::move(p_country)), year(p_year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being constructed.\n";
    }
    President(President&& other) :
            name(std::move(other.name)), country(std::move(other.country)),
            year(other.year)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being moved.\n";
    }
    President& operator=(const President& other) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<President> elections;
    std::cout << "emplace_back:\n";
    elections.emplace_back("Nelson Mandela", "South Africa", 1994);

    std::vector<President> reElections;
    std::cout << "\npush_back:\n";
    reElections.push_back(
            President("Franklin Delano Roosevelt", "the USA", 1936));

    std::cout << "\nContents:\n";

    for (President const& president : elections)
    {
        std::cout << president.name << " was elected president of "
                            << president.country << " in " << president.year << ".\n";
    }

    for (President const& president : reElections)
    {
        std::cout << president.name << " was re-elected president of "
                            << president.country << " in " << president.year << ".\n";
    }
}
```

If you replace `push_back` by `emplace_back` you still have a construction and then a move. Only if you pass the arguments needed for construction instead of the constructed instance itself (see the call to `emplace_back`), you have saved effort.