# emplace_back() vs push_back() for vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, emplace

I knew this has been asked quite a lot, and I have seen many explanations quoting "emplace_back construct in place, push_back() construct and copy". Some posts asked why emplace_back calls the copy constructor because they did not reserve the memory for the vector.

But for the below case, I cannot figure out what emplace_back() achieve more than push_back(). Some answer says "you need to implement a move constructor for emplace_back() to work" But push_back() can also utilize the move constructor. So what is the difference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 

class Int{
    public:
    int* p;
    Int(int x): p(new int(x)) {cout<<"constructor called for "<<*p<<endl;}
    Int(const Int& x): p(new int(*(x.p))) {cout<<"copy constructor called for "<<*p<<endl;}
    ~Int(){
        if (p!= nullptr) {cout<<"destructor called for "<<*p<<endl;}
        else{cout<<"destructor called for null ptr"<<endl;}   
        delete p; 
    }
    
    Int(Int&& x): p(x.p) {
        x.p = nullptr; 
        cout<<"move constructor called for "<<*p<<endl;  // move constructor, remove to test emplace_back()
        }
};

int main(){
    vector<Int> v;
    v.reserve(1);
    v.emplace_back(Int(1));  // can switch to push_back()
    // v.push_back(Int(1));
    cout<<"end program"<<endl;
}
```

For me, it seems both methods call copy constructor without move constructor, and calls move constructor if there is one.

Comment: `v.emplace_back(1);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878001/how-to-choose-between-push-and-emplace-functions/59878611#59878611

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emplace_back` constructs the element in-place by forwarding the arguments to the constructor of element type, so you can

```
v.emplace_back(1); // forwarding 1 to Int::Int(int) to construct the element directly
```

`push_back` always expects an element, i.e. an `Int`. When you pass `1` to it as `v.push_back(1);`, implicit conversion happens. A temporary `Int` is constructed from `1` by `(Int::Int(int)` then passed to `push_back`, the element is constructed from the temporary by the move constructor of `Int` later. I.e. one more move constructor invocation than `v.emplace_back(1);`.

You can also pass an `Int` to `emplace_back` like `v.emplace_back(Int(1));`, as explained above, the temporary `Int` is forwarded to `Int`'s move constructor to construct the element, which does the same thing as `v.push_back(Int(1));`.

As @JeJo suggested, there's another difference between `emplace_back` and `push_back` since C++17. `emplace_back` returns a reference to the inserted element while `push_back` returns nothing.

Comment: @JeJo `but the insert returns nothing.` Maybe I misunderstand, but `std::vector::insert`  doesn't return "nothing". It returns an iterator.

Comment: @JeJo `push_back` returns nothing. Anyway thanks for the reminder, that's a new feature I didn't grasp.