# So if I don't need new features emplace_back (emplace) provides I should use push_back (insert)?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

After asking dummy questions yesterday, experimenting, and reading quite a bunch about `emplace_back` over `push_back`, I'm still not really sure which one I should use "by default", meaning most of the time.

As was pointed out in the answer to popular question "[Why would I ever use push_back instead of emplace_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890653/why-would-i-ever-use-push-back-instead-of-emplace-back)" and in [other articles](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1244731691/can-emplace_back-replace-push_back), the first impression people got after introducing `emplace_back` that "it can do anything that push_back (insert) can do and sometimes can do it better" is wrong.

So far, I have an impression that in cases where I'm using move semantics (or if I need to make I copy), where I can't benefit from the in-place object creation, and when I don't need the return value, it would be safer to use `push_back` not to run into troubles I can get with explicit constructor described in the links, and probably some more.

Simply saying, if I'm not using new features that `emplace_back` has and `push_back`/`insert` doesn't, I better stick with the `push_back`/`insert`.

Am I correct, or am I again missing something?

Comment: The rule is pretty simple.  If you have an object you are adding to the vector. Use push or emplace, they'll do the same thing.  If you have arguments to create an object, instead of creating it and calling push or emplace, call emplace with those parameters so you only get a single object construction.

Comment: @drescherjm emplace_back has return value only since C++17

Comment: If you only want to call implicit constructors, then use `push_back`.

Comment: @NathanOliver as described in the "Why would I ever use push_back instead of emplace_back?" answer using emplace_back in some cases leads to a bugs because of the calls to explicit constructors.

Comment: "only since C++17" - Which you *totally should be using*. 

Comment: @DoehJohn Using any code incorrectly can lead to bugs.  You still need to understand what you are doing.  In that answers example, they should have be using `make_unique` at the call site and they would not have had any issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [push\_back vs emplace\_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)

Comment: you already correctly quote from the other Q&A that emplace can do every thing that pushback can (and more). I heard someone promoting the use of push_back for clarity when emplace is not needed but that is purely opinion-based

Comment: Here's a [cppcon talk](https://youtu.be/oTMSgI1XjF8?t=17m49s) expressing an opinion on this...

Comment: @rustyx I don't know who this guy is but he seems to say the same though I had )

Comment: @idclev463035818 I quoted it to say that it's wrong, as why it's wrong is showed in the links..

Comment: if you refer to the implicit vs explcit constructor difference mentioned in the top answer, then you can still get the same with `emplace_back` if you just go back to first creating an instance, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/DW9Nm8). The answer correctly says that **accidentally** you can do something unwanted, but if you are aware of this difference and you do not want to call explicit constructors then you can do so, also with `emplace_back`. I know my example is a little silly, my point is just that `push_back` doesn't do something that you could not also get with `emplace`

Comment: btw I really first misread your question and I am still convinced that `emplace_back` can do all that `push_back` can. Maybe there is something I am missing, but not using explicit constructors isnt a showstopper

Comment: @idclev463035818 so far my understanding is that yes, emplace_back can do all push_back can do but also more, and sometimes because of that more you can get troubles, so if you don't need the power of emplace_back it's safer to use push_back

Comment: the example with `std::addressof(a)` is an error, whether you use `push_back` or `emplace` and getting a compiler error is of course better than a runtime error. Imho the more convincing case against using `emplace` always is `std::vector<A>{}.emplace_back(A(1,2));`. Accidentally making a copy is much easier to detect in code when you use `push_back` when you need to copy. However, as I said before, it is a matter of choice and purely opinion-based