# c++ vector emplace_back is faster?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a class

```
class foo {
 public:
  foo() { // spend some time and do something. }
 private:
   // some data here
}
```

Now I have a vector of foo, I want to put this vector into another vector

```
vector<foo> input; // assume it has 5 elements
vector<foo> output;
```

Is there ANY performance difference with these two lines?

```
output.push_back(input[0])
output.emplace_back(input[0])
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there ANY performance difference with these two lines?

No, both will initialise the new element using the copy constructor.

`emplace_back` can potentially give a benefit when constructing with more (or less) than one argument:

```
output.push_back(foo{bar, wibble}); // Constructs and moves a temporary
output.emplace_back(bar, wibble);   // Initialises directly
```

The true benefit of `emplace` is not so much in performance, but in allowing non-copyable (and in some cases non-movable) elements to be created in the container.

Comment: "any decent compiler will elide the move and produce the same code in both cases" - I don't think this move is eligible for elision. `push_back(T&&)` will move from a temporary to which a reference has been taken.