# Using *new in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing a simple c++ program in Xcode which has one class Message. In my main I want to declare a new Message and add this to a list messages. Xcode is suggesting I use:

```
messages.push_front(*new Message(messageID));
```

Can anyone explain what the *new does. Am I dynamically allocating memory for the Message object or is it creating a instance of Message on the stack? 
I have checked in Xcode and there are no memory leaks if use this and do not delete the instance so I assume it is allocating on the stack.

Comment: _"I have checked in Xcode and there are no memory leaks if use this and do not delete the instance so I assume it is allocating on the stack."_ How did you check this? Your assumption is completely wrong.

Comment: clearly I have a lot more to learn. I was using Xcode's leaks instrument which I thought wasn't showing any issues. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What type is `messages`? Is it a `std::deque<Message>`? Your code looks like a leak. I wonder if XCode's suggestion is just seeing that you are calling `push_front`, which I suspect takes a `const Message&`, and seeing that you are calling it with a `Message` pointer and so suggests you need to dereference it, without warning you that that's a leak. You probably want `messages.push_front(Message(messageID));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating a `Message` dynamically on the heap and then dereference it to pass it by reference.

One of the overloads of `push_back` is `push_back(const T& value)`, so the value is first allocated on heap then dereferenced and its reference passed to the function.

Now this is useless, as you could directly allocate it with `Message(messageID)` and pass it to the method. In addition you are generating a leak since there is no `delete` associated with `new`, and you can't release it since you don't bind the returned pointer anywhere.

In addition directly passing a `Message(messageID)` and possibly using `emplace_back` instead that `push_back` could save from a copy construction of the object inside the collection.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I also noticed I could use Message(messageID) but was just wondering what *new does as I couldn't find any information on this. 
Extra thanks for the advice on emplace_back. I haven't heard of this and will look into it.

Comment: Here you can find why and how `emplace_back` could be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717151/why-emplace-back-is-faster-than-push-back