# Poor performance of stl list on vs2015 while deleting nodes which contain iterator to self's position in list

Tags: c++, performance, boost, visual-studio-2015, stl

**I am simply storing a list of nodes and each node contains an iterator pointing to its position in the list.Then I am benchmarking time taken to insert and delete nodes for std list and boost list.**

Includes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>    
#include "boost/container/list.hpp"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/make_shared.hpp"

#define ONE_BILLION             1000000000
#define ONE_HUNDRED_MILLION     100000000
#define TEN_MILLION             10000000
#define ONE_MILLION             1000000
#define ONE_HUNDRED_THOUSAND    100000
#define TEN_THOUSAND            10000
```

Helper function to print average duration of insert or delete

```
void print_duration(std::ostream &out, const std::string& str, const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration &d)
{
    out << str << ": ";

    if (d < std::chrono::microseconds(10))
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float, std::nano>>(d).count() << " nano s";
    else if (d < std::chrono::milliseconds(10))
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float, std::micro>>(d).count() << " micro s";
    else if (d < std::chrono::seconds(10))
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>>(d).count() << " milli s";
    else if (d < std::chrono::minutes(10))
        out << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(d).count() << " s";

    out << std::endl;
}
```

STL list

```
struct node
{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>::iterator iter;
};

void measure_list_insert_std(std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>& l)
{
    const size_t count = TEN_THOUSAND;
    size_t i = 0;



    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::make_shared<node>();
        l.push_back(temp);
        temp->iter = --l.end();
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration total = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    print_duration(std::cout, "measure_list_insert_std  ", total / i);
}

void measure_list_delete_std(std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>& l)
{
    const size_t count = TEN_THOUSAND;
    size_t i = 0;

    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (; i < count; ++i)
    {
        //std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>::iterator it = (l.front())->iter;
        l.erase((l.front())->iter);
        //l.pop_back();
        //std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration total = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    print_duration(std::cout, "measure_list_delete_std  ", total / i);
    //std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Boost list

```
struct node_boost
{
    boost::container::list<boost::shared_ptr<node_boost>>::iterator iter;
};

void measure_list_insert_boost(boost::container::list<boost::shared_ptr<node_boost>>& l)
{
    const size_t count = ONE_MILLION;
    size_t i = 0;



    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (; i < count; ++i)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<node_boost> temp = boost::make_shared<node_boost>();
        l.push_back(temp);
        temp->iter = --l.end();
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration total = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    print_duration(std::cout, "measure_list_insert_boost  ", total / i);
}

void measure_list_delete_boost(boost::container::list<boost::shared_ptr<node_boost>>& l)
{
    const size_t count = ONE_MILLION;
    size_t i = 0;

    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (; i < count; ++i)
    {
        //std::list<std::shared_ptr<node>>::iterator it = (l.front())->iter;
        l.erase((l.front())->iter);
        //l.pop_back();
        //std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration total = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - begin;
    print_duration(std::cout, "measure_list_delete_boost  ", total / i);
    //std::cout << l.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    std::list < std::shared_ptr<node>> l;

    measure_list_insert_std(l);
    measure_list_delete_std(l);

    boost::container::list<boost::shared_ptr<node_boost>> l2;
    measure_list_insert_boost(l2);
    measure_list_delete_boost(l2);

    return 0;
}
```

I am simply storing a list of nodes and each node contains an iterator pointing to its position in the list.

Output for above code is:

measure_list_insert_std  : 4830 nano s

measure_list_delete_std  : 431.624 micro s

measure_list_insert_boost  : 4462 nano s

measure_list_delete_boost  : 4248 nano s

If node does not contain the "iterator" element then everything is normal and all outputs are roughly similar.Why in VS2015 implemetation of list is this problem occuring ??

Comment: Performance issue? Use a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to find out _why_!

Comment: How did you compile?

Comment: on VS2015 x64 debug

Comment: Why are you also involving `std::shared_ptr` vs `boost::shared_ptr`?

Comment: std::shared_ptr for stl list and boost::share_ptr for boost list

Comment: Why are you involving any kind of smart pointer?

Comment: its just a test for something else i was implementing

Comment: MSVC debug mode will check iterators, which explains why this unusual case is particularly slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running code to test performance, **always** use *optimization flags*. I had the same issue with [Why emplace_back is faster than push_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717151/why-emplace-back-is-faster-than-push-back), so you are not the first to face that.

On an IDE, for benchmarking , you have to use the *Release mode*, but still using the (always reliable) terminal and the optimization flags of [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) for example should come in mind.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar good! I was in your shoes some time ago, that's why you got my upvote (another +1 in your question). Welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Also, in VS2015, even in Release, if you run the program in the IDE using F5 it will still use the debugging heap and new, frees take much longer. If you use Ctrl-F5 it will run the program with the normal heap. I had an optimized  program speed up a factor of 5 just doing that.

Comment: @doug that's why I mentioned the terminal! Do you think I should updated my answer somehow in relation with your comment?

Comment: Running in a terminal cmd or bash is great but sometimes it's easier to stay in the IDE. It's really a matter of style. I just mentioned it in case there were folks just running with F5 and wondering why performance seemed slow.