# What is the difference between time complexity of string and char array declarations in c++?

Tags: c++, string, performance

In the question [link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DISCHAR) , I first tried it using a character array. This solution exceeded the time limit.

```
    char s[100000];
    cin >> s;
    int cnt[26];
    for(int i=0;i<26;++i)
        cnt[i]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);++i)
        cnt[s[i]-'a']++;
    int count =0;
    for(int i=0;i<26;++i)
        if(cnt[i]>0)
            count++;
    cout << count << endl;
```

But then I changed the above code to this:

```
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int cnt[26];
    for(int i=0;i<26;++i)
        cnt[i]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
        cnt[s.at(i)-'a']++;
    int count =0;
    for(int i=0;i<26;++i)
        if(cnt[i]>0)
            count++;
    cout << count << endl;
```

And the code passed with ease. And also the first one exceeded the time limit of 1 sec, while the second one passed with time of execution of 0.04 sec. Why is there such a large difference in time of execution?

Comment: What is the length of the input?

Comment: size of string < 100000

Comment: save yourself  a `for` loop: `int cnt[26] = {0}`. And a bit of time can be saved here: `cnt[s.at(i)-'a']++;` because `at` tests that you haven't overrun the string. You've already guaranteed this with the bounds on the for loop so you can `cnt[s[i]-'a']++;`. There may be some optimizing games the compiler can play with a ranged for loop: `for(char ch: s) cnt[ch-'a']++;`. And if not, the code's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C strings do not store length explicily, they just have a null atbthe end. So to work out the length you need to iterate over the entire string character by character. 'sid::string::length' on the otherhand just returns the internally stored length.

You can easily speed up the C version though, by caching the length in a variable before the loop and using the cached length in the for statement.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` stores its length separately, so `s.size()` is an instant operation.

`for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);++i)` calls `strlen(s)` on every iteration, and `strlen` loops through the entire string to the end to find the length of the string. So this innocent looking loop is actually O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

Comment: But in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681109/how-is-time-complexity-different , I had asked that whether strlen() is called once or every time in the loop. But then the answer given was that it is called only once....is it not so?

Comment: @yobro97 It depends on how smart the compiler is. It seems that in this case the compiler isn't smart enough. Are you compiling with optimization turned on?

Comment: @orlp....Actually I have run this program on an online competitive programming environment....so no idea...:(

Comment: @yobro97: That's not what the answers there say. It says the compiler, under ideal conditions with optimizations turned on, could _potentially_ optimize out the repeated `strlen` calls. There are no guarantees there. It's much better to be explicit about calling `strlen` once, so you're not dependent on the optimizer making a tough call correctly. Since you don't even control optimization settings, you have no way to know if it will even _try_.

Comment: its right.....I tried declaring `int n = strlen(s)`  as mentioned by @doron and then use `n` instead of `strlen(s)` in the loop, it worked!

Comment: C does not have function purity so there is no guaratee that calling the same function more than once will return the same result. The means that the compiler is never allowed to cache the return value.

Comment: @doron - On the other hand, everyone knows what `strlen` does, even the compiler. And it can optimize on that knowledge.

Comment: Only if it is a compiler intrinsic and I don't think it is.