# push_back vs emplace_back with a volatile

Tags: c++

The following code fails for `push_back` and succeeds for `emplace_back`:

```
#include <vector>
volatile int x = 0;
int main()
{        
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(x);
    vec.push_back(x); // error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::push_back(volatile int&)'
}
```

I understand that `push_back` failes because it takes a reference and tries to cast away `volatile` qualifier implicitly from that reference.

However, `emplace_back` *also* takes a reference (rvalue-references are references). Why is it treated differently?

Comment: maybe this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

Comment: I understand this is not really the question, but if you need a workaround convert the type: `vec.push_back(static_cast<int>(x));` (alternatively `int(x)` or `(int)x`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because of how they are defined in the C++11 Standard. Paragraph 23.3.6.1 specifies their signature:

```
template <class... Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args);
void push_back(const T& x);
void push_back(T&& x);
```

While the parameters of the available overloads of `push_back()` do not have any `volatile` qualification, the argument of the `emplace_back()` function template can bind to lvalues with any `cv`-qualification.

> However, emplace_back also takes a reference (rvalue-references are references). Why is it ttreated differently?

Yes, because `emplace_back()` is a function *template*, and type deduction will infer `Args` to be an argument pack of length one, whose only element has type `int volatile&` (see Paragraph 14.8.2.1/3).

The overloads of `push_back()`, on the other hand, are regular member functions of the `std::vector<>` class template, and there is no type deduction going on when invoking them. Since references to non-`volatile` cannot bind to objects qualified as `volatile` (see Paragraph 8.5.3/4-5), the compiler won't be able to resolve the call.