# time complexity of reserve on an empty vector vs. a deque and whether to use emplace or push_back

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, deque, push-back

I am debating which is going to be faster, if I am using a data structure to store call backs within a class should I use a vector and reserve on start up or should I just use a deque in this case since the total number of subscribers is not known but will be relatively small say around 15.  I guess what is the trade off in these two scenarios allocating each time versus taking the hit to reserve up front in my class.

```
#ifndef __Pricer_hpp__
#define __Pricer_hpp__

#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Pricer
{
  public: 
    typedef  void (*callback_fn)(double price, void *subscription);

    Pricer(): _initialSubscriberNum(15), _callbacks() { _callbacks.reserve(_initialSubscriberNum); }  // is it better to use a deuqe and remove the need for the reserve?

    void attach (const callback_fn& fn, void *subscription )
    {
      _callbacks.emplace_back(fn,subscription); // is emplace_back better than using push_back with std::pair construction which I am assuming would do a move version of push_back?  
    }

    void broadcast(double price)
    {
      for ( auto callback : _callbacks)
      {
        (*callback.first)(price, callback.second);
      }
    }

  private:
    typedef std::pair<callback_fn, void *> _callback_t;
    const unsigned int _initialSubscriberNum;
    std::vector<_callback_t> _callbacks; // should this be a deque?
};

#endif
```

Comment: 15 is tiny. It's unlikely you'll be able to measure any difference at all between using either container with `push_back` or `emplace`.

Comment: `__Pricer_hpp__` is a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/981959), stop using it

Comment: thanks for the heads up on reserved names. It seems any _[a-zA-Z] shouldn't be used as the standard can reserve those as well with the capital letters being worse, also it seems _t suffix shouldn't be used if you use POSIX. How do you name your private vars with an underbar after the name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

general suggestion is to use a vector and then if you have some performance problems (which in your cases will not happen probably) change to some other data structure.

Remember about ["premature optimization"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) that sometimes can hurt.

**push_back** vs **emplace_back**: [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)

Comment: makes sense. thanks for the info, I was thinking about in the future where you might have say 100+ clients but I agree it is probably fine to just use a vector in this case. What about the emplace_back vs. push_back part of the question?

Comment: 100 is still quite a small number :)