# How do I add elements to an empty vector in a loop?

Tags: c++, vector, insert

I am trying to create an empty vector inside a loop, and want to add an element to the vector each time something is read in to that loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::vector<float> myVector();

   float x;
   while(cin >> x)
      myVector.insert(x);

   return 0;
}
```

But this is giving me error messages.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Most vexing parse problem. Get rid of the parentheses in the declaration of `myVector`.

Comment: yes this was my exact problem. and i now understand i need to use push_back thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to use [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead:

```
while(cin >> x)
  myVector.push_back(x);
//         ^^^^^^^^^
```

and not [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), which, as you can see in the link, needs an iterator to indicate the position where you want to insert the element.

Also, as [what @Joel has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984268/how-do-i-add-elements-to-an-empty-vector-in-a-loop/17984286#comment26293169_17984268), you should remove the parentheses in your vector variable's definition.

```
std::vector<float> myVector;
```

and **not**

```
std::vector<float> myVector();
```

By doing the latter, you run into C++'s [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem.

Comment: As my edit suggested, this answer is wrong. You do not Need to use push_back, you May. You Can use insert as is obvious.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

```
while(cin >> x)
  myVector.push_back(x);
```

The [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) function takes an iterator as the first argument, indicating the position to insert.

Also, you need to get rid of the parentheses in the declaration of `myVector`:

```
std::vector<float> myVector;
```

Comment: The problem is that I keep receiving the following error message whenever i decide to use a method: "request for 'push_back' in myVector which is of non-class type std::"

Comment: @AmberRoxanna  Use `std::vector<float> myVector;` instead of `std::vector<float> myVector();`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `myVector.insert()`, 
use it like `myVector.insert(myVector.end(), x)`. This will append x at the end of myVector.
You can insert x in the beginning by `myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), x)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `std::vector::emplace_back()` instead of `std::vector::push_back()`. The makes some optimizations and doesn't take an argument of type `vector::value_type`, it takes variadic arguments that are forwarded to the constructor of the appended item, while `push_back` can make unnecessary copies or movements.

This is demonstrated in the [std::vector::emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) documentation and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) is a related question.

Usage example:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;

while (cin >> x) {
    myVector.emplace_back(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below may answer your question and also brings some other examples regarding how to insert new elements in different position or index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vector_of_integers{};

    vector_of_integers.push_back(1); // O(1)
    vector_of_integers.push_back(3); // O(1)
    vector_of_integers.push_back(5); // O(1)
    vector_of_integers.push_back(7); // O(1)

    for (int i = 8; i <= 10; i++)
        vector_of_integers.push_back(i);

    // Printing out all the elements of vector of integers - Method 1
    copy(vector_of_integers.begin(), vector_of_integers.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); // 1 3 5 7 8 9 10
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Inserting '2' at index 1
    vector<int>::iterator it{ vector_of_integers.begin() };
    advance(it, 1);
    vector_of_integers.insert(it, 2); // O(N+M) => M is size of elements to be inserted

    // Printing out all the elements of vector of integers - Method 2
    for (auto const& element : vector_of_integers)
        std::cout << element << " "; // 1 2 3 5 7 8 9 10
    cout << endl << endl;

    // "it" no longer valid, get a new one
    it = vector_of_integers.begin();
    vector_of_integers.insert(it + 4, 6); // O(N+M) => M is size of elements to be inserted

    // Printing out all the elements of vector of integers - Method 3
    for (it = vector_of_integers.begin(); it != vector_of_integers.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << ' '; // 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
    cout << endl << endl;

    // insert '4' 7 times at index 3
    vector<int> new_vector_to_be_inserted(7, 4);
    vector_of_integers.insert(vector_of_integers.begin() + 3, new_vector_to_be_inserted.begin(), new_vector_to_be_inserted.end()); // O(N+M) => M is size of elements to be inserted

    // Printing out all the elements of vector of integers - Method 4
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_of_integers.size(); i++)
        cout << vector_of_integers.at(i) << ' '; // 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```