# Using push_back with rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using push_back with rvalue references?

I have the following code:

```
csvData.push_back(CsvDataSet(csvBlock));
```

Should I instead do this:

```
csvData.push_back(std::move(CsvDataSet(csvBlock)));
```

That way I save one copy operation.

Comment: You should make it clear wether `CsvDataSet` is a class or a function returning some value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `CsvDataSet` to be a class: No, you shouldn't. `CsvDataSet(csvBlock)` is already an *rvalue*. More precisely, it is an *prvalue*.

Therefore in both cases, `void std::vector::push_back( T&& value );` will be called.

Comment: OK I should remove the templates from my code. It was a question about classes in general, not templates.

Comment: Aha I get it, so that is already a temporary value, that is an rvalue. Nice!

Comment: The result of calling a *converting constructor* is a **prvalue**.

Comment: Why should it make a difference, if the constructor is declared explicit or not?

Comment: @MWid, yeah, you are right. Had a little bit of confusion going on there reading the standard. Could you please check if the current version is ok? Thanks.

Comment: @Jefffrey Everything is fine!

Answer (score 6):

I think in your case you should use [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

"Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed. The constructor of the element is called with exactly the same arguments that are supplied to the function."

Not sure, but I think it is equivalent for using `push_back(std::move(T()))`, but maybe the downvoter correct me, please. *Clarification* the result should be the same, but `emplace` forwards arguments to constructor and constructs elements in place, while `push_back` calls `move` constructor, or normal one and then moves object.

Edit: if the downvoter agrees with the reasoning presented by @user3111311 below I urge to read *Example* section in [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: emplace_back is redundant in c++11, push_back should be used instead

Comment: @user3111311 What?! Can you back it up? It was introduced in c++11. Why would the standard committee include something redundant? Is that an aesthetic opinion?

Comment: emplace_back was meant to be an "efficient" version of push_back. Now that we have push_back for rvalue references, it is not needed. It is kept in c++11 for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @user3111311 For backwards compatibility with what? Both  `emplace_back` and `void push_back( T&& value )` are introduced in the same version of standard. Unless cppreference is wrong. There is no "now". `Emplace` constructs object in-place, `push_back` moves it. Therefore in your case you get called a constructor, and move instead of just constructor called.

Comment: @user3111311 `emplace_back` is not redundant in C++11. There are specific forms of `emplace_back` that was provided by different compilers that are non comformant and redundant ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)). However the correct form of `emplace_back` taking the constructor parameters directly e.g. `csvData.emplace_back(csvBlock)` is **not** redundant. It will construct the object in place instead of performing a move construct as `void push_back(T&&)`

Comment: @user3111311 IT is in fact *`push_back`* that is redundant in C++11, since `emplace_back` encompasses its functionality.

Comment: @Casey I wouldn't go as far. `emplace_back` just forwards arguments to the constructor, u might want to move an already constructed the element onto the list. `emplace` cannot do that. But calling constructor as argument in `push_back()` seem of little sense to me.

Comment: @luk32 Yes, `emplace` can do that. Passing a `T const&` or `T&&` to `emplace_back` has identical effect to passing a `T const&` or `T&&` to `push_back`.