# how to write data in vector<vector<float>*>*?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to allocate space for vector of vector but after allocation gdb showing null in `pVectorTemp_` but showing size 2

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 
int main( )
{ 
    int index1 = 2;
    int index2 = 2;
    vector<vector<float>*>* pVectorTemp_ =  NULL;
    pVectorTemp_  = new vector<vector<float>*>();
    pVectorTemp_->resize(index1);
    for(unsigned int i=0 ;i< index1;i++)
    {
        vector<float>* pvecTemp = new vector<float>();
        pvecTemp->resize(index2);
        (*pVectorTemp_)[index1] = (pvecTemp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gdb :

```
(gdb) pvector  pVectorTemp_
elem[0]: $2 = (std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > *) 0x0
elem[1]: $3 = (std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > *) 0x0
Vector size = 2
Vector capacity = 2
```

So Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: You really don't need to use pointers and dynamic allocation here.

Comment: `(*pVectorTemp_)[index1]` this line is wrong, should be `(*pVectorTemp_)[i]`.

Comment: "Am i doing anything wrong" Yes. You are using pointers.

Comment: @n.m. Raw owning pointers.

Comment: In other words, use `vector<vector<float>>` (or just `vector<float>`) and drop all those `new`s.

Comment: `vector<vector<float>*>*` — *Cannot compute this* — Use (preferably) C++ with `std::vector` and no pointers at all or use C with pointers, don’t create Frankenstein’s monster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop body, you have:

> ```
> (*pVectorTemp_)[index1] = (pvecTemp);
> ```

But note that the index of the `for` loop is **`i`** (`index1` is the upper bound).

So, I think you have a typo or bug, and you may want to use `i` (not `index1`) as index inside `[...]`.

Note also that you have a `signed`/`unsigned` mismatch, since in the loop you have `unsigned int` as index, and you compare that with `index1`, which is a signed integer.

---

But, anyway, your code is uselessly complicated.

You don't need to allocate all these vectors on the heap with `new`.
Just use *automatic* (*"stack"*) allocation, e.g.:

```
int main()
{ 
    int index1 = 2;
    int index2 = 2;

    // Your original code is commented out:
    //
    // vector<vector<float>*>* pVectorTemp_ =  NULL;
    // pVectorTemp_  = new vector<vector<float>*>();
    vector<vector<float>> vectorTemp;

    // pVectorTemp_->resize(index1);
    // Just consider calling push_back.

    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
    {
        // vector<float>* pvecTemp = new vector<float>();        
        // pvecTemp->resize(index2);
        // (*pVectorTemp_)[index1] = (pvecTemp);
        vectorTemp.push_back(vector<float>(index2));
    }

    // No need for return 0 in main().
    // return 0;
}
```

See how the code gets simplified!

(Code without comments follows.)

```
int main()
{ 
    int index1 = 2;
    int index2 = 2;

    vector<vector<float>> vectorTemp;        
    for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++)
    {
        vectorTemp.push_back(vector<float>(index2));
    }
}
```

---

As a further improvement, assuming that your C++ STL implementation provides that, you may want to use **`emplace_back()`** instead of `push_back()`, to build the nested vectors:

```
// Instead of vectorTemp.push_back(vector<float>(index2));
//
vectorTemp.emplace_back(index2);
```

In this case, a `vector` of size `index2` is built directly into the `vectorTemp` ("outer" vector) container, without temporaries.

You may want to read also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4303513/1629821) on StackOverflow for further details:

> [**push_back vs. emplace_back**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4303513/1629821)

Comment: @Jefffrey: Raw loops are just fine and very clear in several cases. No need to obfuscate the code with the latest feature.

Comment: `std::vector`'s constructor is not "*the latest feature*" by all means.

Comment: I was referring to your critics to my use of raw loops, which to me are fine and clear in several cases.

Answer (score 1):

These are the things I can find.

```
vector<vector<float>*>* pVectorTemp1 =  new vector<vector<float>*>(); // (1)(4)
pVectorTemp1->resize(index1);
for (int i=0 ; i < index1; i++) { // (2)
    vector<float>* pvecTemp2 = new vector<float>(); /(4)
    pvecTemp2->resize(index2);
    (*pVectorTemp1)[i] = (pvecTemp2); // (3)
}
```

1. Variables that differ only by trailing underscore is asking for trouble.
2. `unsigned` adds nothing, except the risk of  a signed/unsigned mistake
3. The index should be `i` not `index1`.
4. It would be better to use local variables rather than heap allocation and pointers, but that would change the code too much.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(*pVectorTemp_)[index1] = (pvecTemp);
```

with

```
(*pVectorTemp_)[i] = (pvecTemp);
```

Answer (score 1):

> So Am i doing anything wrong?

Yes, you are doing something wrong:

- using dynamically allocation when not needed
- using unnecessary raw loops

Here's a simplified version:

```
int main( )
{ 
    int index1 = 2;
    int index2 = 2;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> pVectorTemp_
        ( index1
        , std::vector<float>(index2) );
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/191c6cc2058c50b8)