# Why does an object get destroyed when pushing it to a vector?

Tags: c++

I would like to know why an element I push back into a vector gets its destructor called in this situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a)
     : m_a(a)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo ctor() " << m_a << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo dtor() " << m_a << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
};

class FooStorage
{
public:
    static void createFoo(int a)
    {
        m_foos.push_back(Foo(a));
    }

    static std::vector<Foo> m_foos;
};

std::vector<Foo> FooStorage::m_foos;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Before: " << FooStorage::m_foos.size() << std::endl;
    FooStorage::createFoo(53);
    std::cout << "After: " << FooStorage::m_foos.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
Before: 0
Foo ctor() 53
Foo dtor() 53
After: 1
Foo dtor() 53
```

I'd like to know:

- What gets deleted? (inbetween the 'Before' and 'After' couts)
- Why does it get deleted?
- What ends up in the vector?

Comment: What is the point of the FooStorage class? It just makes it harder to read.

Comment: You are copying it to your vector, use Foo& or Foo* for the storage if you do not want copy

Comment: Use emplace_back to create the object directly into the vector.

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig Using references will not work as they are not copyable.

Comment: I suggest you study e.g. [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @NeilKirk `FooStorage` seems to be a factory and a storage container for `Foo`s

Comment: @NeilKirk `emplace_back` seems to still cause the destructor to be called there.

Comment: `Foo(a)` creates a temporary object which is either moved or copied when the call to `push_back()` occurs. The moved to or copied to object is then stored in the `vector` while the temporary object's destructor gets invoked.

Comment: How do you call emplace back? `m_foos.emplace_back(a);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're creating a temporary object here:

```
m_foos.push_back(Foo(a));
//               ^^^^^^
```

That object's destructor will be called when the full expression has ended, but it will have been copied (or moved) by `push_back()` into the vector.

To prevent the creation of a temporary you can construct in-place using `emplace_back()`:

```
m_foos.emplace_back(a);
```

Comment: This does not work on IDE, the IDEs ARE the problem. Try compiling from the terminal.

Comment: Nothing appears from the compiler or at running time, but the results are completely false and suffer from undefined behavior. Check the accepted answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

I posted this comment because I spent a few hours debugging a bug coming from CLion and the code was running completly fine from the terminal. In such case, I did not need `emplace_back` `push_back` worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
m_foos.push_back(Foo(a));
```

This would result in two constructor call ( **but it entirely depends on the compiler it can optimize away**).

```
Foo(a)
```

is a temporary which would be constructed ( one constructor call )and then copied to vector ( copy constructor called ). As usual temporaries are alive till the end of expression where they are used. So when push_back ends it would call destructor for this temporary ( that's why you are seeing a call to destructor).

Comment: The copy/move constructor can't be elided here. Which one is called, depends. In this case it is copy ctor, because there is user-declared destructor.