# Can I use a `unique_ptr` in a vector, or do I need to switch to `shared_ptr`?

Tags: c++, std

Given this class with a unique_ptr:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(){}
  MyClass(MyClass &&other) : ptr(std::move(other.ptr)){}

  std::unique_ptr <int> ptr;
};
```

Is there any way to make it possible to have a `std::vector<MyClass>`?

```
void ThisBreaksIt()
{
  MyClass instance;
  std::vector<MyClass> mv;
  mv.push_back(instance);
}
```

As-is, this gives me the error

```
error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
```

This makes sense, since I have no copy constrctor, and when the compiler tries creating a default copy constructor, it tries copying the `unique_ptr`, which isn't allowed.

I can make it compile by adding this constructor:

```
  MyClass(const MyClass&){}
```

But of course, this leaves the `unique_ptr` uninitialized, and is not what I want.

I can't add

```
  MyClass(const MyClass& other) : ptr(std::move(other.ptr)){}
```

because it's `const`, and I cant call std::move() on a `const` object. I can create the constructor

```
  MyClass(MyClass& other) : ptr(std::move(other.ptr)){}
```

but doesn't solve the original compile error, as `vector::push_back` uses a `const` copy constructor.

So, I'm stuck.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

All of these issues go away if I just use a `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`. Is that what I should be doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem storing a non-copyable type in a vector; it's only required to be movable, as yours is.

The problem is that this:

```
mv.push_back(instance);
```

tries to insert a copy of `instance`, and the class is not copyable. But it is movable:

```
mv.push_back(std::move(instance));
```

Note that there's no need to write your own default and move constructors in this example. The implicit ones will do the exactly what yours do.

Comment: You will get similar error symptoms if you write "vector<unique_ptr<X>> myVector = someOtherVector" instead of properly declaring myVector to be a reference. VS2010 especially will give you very misleading error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emplace_back. This only allows adding rvalues.

Therefore do this:

```
void ThisShouldFixIt()
{
  mv.emplace_back(MyClass());
}
```

Note that emplace_back can call the applicable constructor 
of T implace, as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back). For what you are doing
push_back is fine though, given that a version taking an rvalue 
reference does exist.

Comment: `emplace_back` doesn't really change anything here; `mv.push_back(MyClass())` would also be fine. `emplace_back` is for when you want to pass constructor parameters to create an object in place, rather than passing an existing object to move or copy.

Comment: Agreed. I've changed my answer as I consider it worthwhile being aware of the benefits of emplace.