# Can't add elements of a struct type to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm trying to add two values into a vector of a custom type, without creating a variable of that type.

```
typedef struct duo{
    int uniqueID; 
    double data; 
};

vector<duo> myVector;
myVector.push_back({1,1.0});
```

But it won't allow it??

The only way I can get it to work is if I create the variable, but feels tedious...

```
vector<duo> myVector;
duo temp = {1,1.0};
myVector.push_back(temp);
```

Also... why can't I do this?

```
duo temp;
temp = {1,1.0};
```

but I can do this:

```
duo temp = {1,1.0};
```

???

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Your code should compile if you're using a C++11 compiler. And that `typedef` is of no use.

Comment: Please don't edit to include multiple questions. If you have a new question, ask it separately.

Comment: I'm using both MSVC compiler and Intel compiler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back useful link for this question

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid creating the temporary object while building your vector using [std::vector::emplace_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Below is the code sample.

```
class duo {
public:
    duo(int uniqueID_, double data_)
        : uniqueID(uniqueID_)
        , data(data_) {}

private:        
    int uniqueID; 
    double data; 
};


int main() {
    vector<duo> myVector;
    myVector.emplace_back(1, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a C++11 compiler, compile the .cpp file using `g++ -std=c++11`. Also, remove `typedef` from the definition of the `struct duo`.

Otherwise you can create a parameterized constructor for `duo` and then use the constructor for `push_back` the `duo` objects into the vector.

Code:

```
struct duo {
    int uniqueID; 
    double data; 
    duo(int _uniqueID, double _data) : uniqueID{_uniqueID}, data{_data} {}
};

vector<duo> myVector;
myVector.push_back(duo(1,1.0)); //This compiles.
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: If you are on Linux, open the Terminal; If on Windows, open Command Prompt. Reach to the directory where your .cpp file is present. Let the .cpp file name be x.cpp . So, write `g++ -std=c++11 x.cpp -o x` if on Linux **or** `g++ -std=c++11 x.cpp -o x.exe` if on Windows. You will have no errors in compilation then.