# initializing a c++ vector with values

Tags: c++

I need to init my vector with a class I have created holding x,y double values.
is there a better way to init it?

```
std::vector<CentroidXY> centroids;
CentroidXY temp = CentroidXY(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938);
centroids.push_back(temp);
temp = CentroidXY(1843.890860395045,1694.073652494);
centroids.push_back(temp);
temp = CentroidXY(1852.11101474414,1354.88360797918);
centroids.push_back(temp);
```

here is CentroidXY.cpp

```
#include "CentroidXY.h"

CentroidXY::CentroidXY(double X, double Y)
{
    m_X = X;
    m_Y = Y;
}
CentroidXY::CentroidXY(void)
{
}

CentroidXY::~CentroidXY(void)
{
}
```

here is CentroidXY.h

```
#pragma once
class CentroidXY
{
public:
    CentroidXY(double X, double Y);
    CentroidXY(void);
    ~CentroidXY(void);

    double m_X;
    double m_Y;
};
```

Comment: You really don't need `temp`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. However I got a -1, so if you find any bug (if the -1 is for this reason) please let me know, so that the future readers won't face it!

Comment: @G.Samaras your code works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an initialization list, so change this:

```
CentroidXY::CentroidXY(double X, double Y)
{
    m_X = X;
    m_Y = Y;
}
```

to this:

```
CentroidXY::CentroidXY(double X, double Y) : m_X(X), m_Y(Y)
{ }
```

[Source](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Moreover, you could change this (since you don't need `temp`):

```
CentroidXY temp = CentroidXY(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938);
centroids.push_back(temp);
```

to this:

```
centroids.push_back(CentroidXY(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938));
```

or (which is equivalent to calling push_back):

```
centroids.emplace_back(CentroidXY(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938));
```

or even better:

```
centroids.emplace_back(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938);
```

That way the code is cleaner.

Interesting link: [push_back vs emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)

Comment: Also, `emplace_back` could be used.

Comment: I guess you should use `centroids.emplace_back(1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938);`

Comment: What @RuggeroTurra said. Otherwise you're emplacing using one of the copy constructors, which is the same as calling `push_back` in the first place :-)

Comment: Thank you @RuggeroTurra, edited! Agreed juanchopanza!

Comment: I got a -1 and I would like to know if there is a bug, so that I can edit! Think of the future readers!

Answer (score 3):

Could use:

```
auto centroids = std::vector<CentroidXY>() = {
    { 1504.907526094, 1345.27375938 },
    { 1852.11101474414, 1354.88360797918 }
};
```

or if you can't stand Almost Always Auto (AAA), use:

```
std::vector<CentroidXY> centroids = {
    { 1504.907526094, 1345.27375938 },
    { 1852.11101474414, 1354.88360797918 }
};
```

Comment: Very nice answer, +1! :) Pity I did not include it to my answer!

Comment: Yes.  The Standard is The Standard I guess.

Comment: I mentioned it because the OP tagged the question `C++` and not `C++11`

Comment: @GargAnkit I'm not using c++11 so I can't use this answer.

Comment: The answer you ticked includes emplace_back, which is C++11.

Comment: Why do you propose a complicated code like `auto centroids = std::vector<CentroidXY>() = {{ 1504.907526094, 1345.27375938 },...`? Wouldn't the following one be simpler? `std::vector<CentroidXY> centroids = {{ 1504.907526094, 1345.27375938 }, ...};`

Comment: I use "auto" for all declarations except class members.  It's not "complicated".  It's simple C++.  And Garg you posted a reply that included "new" with push_back, so I would be a little more circumspect if I were you.  See http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/.

Comment: @Robinson I am not saying that you are wrong. I am only saying that the solution you gave isn't useful in this context. That's it.

Comment: If my answer is wrong because it's up to date with the current C++ standard, so is the answer the OP accepted as it uses a C++11 function (emplace).

Comment: Well, that's not my call to take!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
std::vector<CentroidXY> centroids;
centroids.push_back( CentroidXY( 1504.907526094 , 1345.27375938 ) );
centroids.push_back( CentroidXY( 1843.890860395045, 1694.073652494 ) );
centroids.push_back( CentroidXY( 1852.11101474414, 1354.88360797918 ) );
```

Comment: I am not the guy who gave you the -1, but `new` should probably be the reason. See my answer Garg, you were close. :)

Comment: Who cares about the downvote! Can you still throw some light on why `new` isn't correct here?

Comment: Well, there isn't any need for calling `new`, and it will most likely result in a compiler error, or a memory leak.

Comment: Also if calling new, the pointer should be `delete`d when it is no longer required in order to reduce the possibility of a memory leak.