# Pushing back an object in a vector without the object

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, push-back

I know that the correct way of push back an object in a vector is to declare an object of the same class and pass it by value as argument of method push_back. i.e. something like

```
class MyClass{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<MyClass> myvector;

    MyClass myobject;
    myobject.a = 1;
    myobject.b = 2;
    myobject.c = 3;

    myvector.push_back(myobject);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: it's possible to push back an object passing only the values of the object and not another object? i.e. something like

```
class MyClass{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<MyClass> myvector;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    myvector.push_back({a, b, c});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your class' members were public, then you could say `myvector.push_back({a, b, c});`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you declare `a`, `b`, `c` as `public`,

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

then you could use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
myvector.push_back({a, b, c});
```

But it could be better to make a constructor

```
MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b, int c):
    a(a), b(b), c(c)
{}
```

and then use [vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

```
myvector.emplace_back(a, b, c);
```

Comment: `emplace_back()` was added in C++11. For earlier versions, defining a constructor is still useful, then you can do this: `myvector.push_back(MyClass(a, b, c));`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need at least a C++11 compiler and you need to make a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    MyClass(int a_, int b_, int c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}
};
```

You could also make `a`, `b` and `c` public, but I'm guessing you don't want to do that, as it changes the interface of the class.

In response to your question "why is `emplace_back` better or more efficient than `push_back`":

By design, `emplace_back()` should avoid creating a temporary object and should construct "in place" at the end of the vector. With `push_back({a, b, c})` you create a temporary `MyClass` object, which is then copied to the end of the vector. Of course, compiler optimizations may actually lead to same code being generated in both cases, but, by default, `emplace_back()` should be more efficient. This is further discussed here: [push_back vs emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) .

Comment: I'm assuming you are suggesting for `emplace_back` but you don't state so.

Comment: @NeilKirk Actually `push_back({a, b, c})` would work as well (with a constructor or with public data). (`emplace_back` is slightly better, but that is another story.)

Comment: @NeilKirk Using emplace_back() is fine, the question, at least how I got it, was in the spirit of "is this possible with push_back" , more so than "what is the most efficient way to do it". Also, AlexD already covered emplace_back().

Comment: The answers provided satisfy my needs. Anyway, why `emplace_back` is better or more efficient than `push_back`?