# Passing object by unique_ptr or by value and how to implement

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, parameter-passing, smart-pointers

I have a case that I am not sure if I should use `unique_ptr` or pass Object by values.

Say that I have class A which  has a vector Of class B and Class C has a vector of class B as well. Every time I am adding a B Object to Vector in class C it should be Removed from vector of Class C and vice versa. When Object C is destroyed all the objects in B Vector class should be add to B vector in class A

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
};

class A {
    C & c;
    std::vector<B> bs;
public:
    A(C & c ): c(c){};
    virtual ~A();
    void add(B b){
        bs.push_back(b);
        c.remove(b);
    }
    void remove(B b){
        bs.erase(std::remove(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b), bs.end());
    }
};

class C {
public:
     A & a;
    std::vector<B> bs;
    C(A & a): a(a) {

    };
    virtual ~C(){
        for (B b : bs) {
                a.add(b);
                remove(b);
            }
    }

    void add(B b){
        bs.push_back(b);
        a.remove(b);
    }
    void remove(B b){
        bs.erase(std::remove(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b), bs.end());
    }
};
```

My questions:

1. Is it better to use pointers in this case? I should always have a unique Object for B! In other words if content of two b objects are different they are still different because different address in memory.
2. I want to write this code with help of smart_pointers in C++ 11! Which type is better `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`? A B object is never owned by two objects and it has always one owner so I guess `unique_ptr` is better but I am not sure.
3. **How Can I write the code above using unique_ptr?**

Comment: Most of the time you should not think of the new smart pointers as pointers in the same way as normal non-smart pointers. Instead you should look at them as resource ownership. Should a resource have only a single owner at a time (`std::unique_ptr`) or can a resource have multiple simultaneous owners (`std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: You should use a `std::unique_ptr` as it sounds from your requirements.

Comment: always prefer unique_ptr for your choice of smart pointers

Comment: plz ask ur question in a clearer manner, what do u actually want to do

Comment: @CPPNITR I want to write above code using unique_ptr<B> instead of B In classes A and C

Comment: @CppNITR plz don't use l337 speech!

Comment: @Govan As mentioned you're on the right track IMHO. Can you clarify which particular problem(s) you are stuck with changing to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my problem is void remove(B b){
        bs.erase(std::remove(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b), bs.end());
    } method. How to write that using unique_ptr. When I am removing nique_ptr and add method. Same as Add and destructor

Comment: @Govan What ever it is, edit your question to clarify!

Comment: You can only have one unique_ptr per object instance. With the current code this rule is violated in several places which leads to compile errors as unique_ptr won't let you make copies (and don't try to trick it as it will result in runtime errors anyway as objects will be deleted to early). Maybe it is possible to not violate any of these cases using std::move and std::forward but I think you are much better of using std::shared_ptr in this case.

Comment: Can the vectors contain duplicates? Your add functions only add one element to the vector but delete all matching elements from the other vector.

Comment: Can you provide example usage code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If copy-constructing `B` is costly, then (smart)pointers are probably a good idea (redesigning the application logic might be another solution),
2. If I understood correctly, a given `B` instance is always manipulated by a single owner (either `A` or `C`). `std::unique_ptr` is therefore a reasonable choice,
3. Try the following implementation. I haven't compiled it but I think you'll get the general idea :)

.

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
};

class A {
    C & c;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;
public:
    A(C & c ): c(c){};
    virtual ~A();
    // http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/
    // (c) Passing unique_ptr by value means "sink."
    void add(std::unique_ptr<B> b){
        c.remove(b);               // release the poiner from the other container
        bs.emplace_back(b.get());  // emplace the pointer in the new one
        b.release();               // emplacement successful. release the pointer
    }
    // http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/
    // (d) Passing unique_ptr by reference is for in/out unique_ptr parameters.
    void remove(std::unique_ptr<B>& b){
        // @todo check that ther returned pointer is != bs.end()
        std::find(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b)->release();             // first release the pointer
        bs.erase(std::remove(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b), bs.end());  // then destroy its owner
    }
};

class C {
public:
    A & a;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> bs;
    C(A & a): a(a) {

    };
    virtual ~C(){
        for (auto&& b : bs) {
            a.add(b);
            // a is going to call this->remove()...
            // unless calling this->remove() from "a"
            // while this is being destroyed is Undefined Behavior (tm)
            // I'm not sure :)
        }
    }
    // http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/
    // (c) Passing unique_ptr by value means "sink."
    void add(std::unique_ptr<B> b){
        c.remove(b);               // release the poiner from the other container
        bs.emplace_back(b.get());  // emplace the pointer in the new one
        b.release();               // emplacement successful. release the pointer
    }
    // http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/
    // (d) Passing unique_ptr by reference is for in/out unique_ptr parameters.
    void remove(std::unique_ptr<B>& b){
        // @todo check that ther returned pointer is != bs.end()
        std::find(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b)->release();             // first release the pointer
        bs.erase(std::remove(bs.begin(), bs.end(), b), bs.end());  // then destroy its owner
    }
};
```

Comment: may I ask why are you using emplace_back instead of push_back

Comment: It's [a little bit more efficient that `push_back()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) because it constructs a new object from the given arguments, typically using [placement-new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new), instead of calling a copy or move constructor like push_back))

Comment: At the point that your `A::add` is called `b` apparently has two owners. It is owned by the local `b` variable but also owned by `c`. I thought the idea was that each `b` object would have one unique owner? I don't think you can work around the problem just by using `release`. How do you expect your `add` to be used?

Comment: I guess the OP would have to provide more context for me to answer that particular question :) In the provided solution, I was just trying to adhere to  what seemed (for me) to be the original code's logic.

Comment: @ChrisDrew yes every B object should have just one owner always. However the code is just an example. In the real code A and C doesn't know each other and the responsiblity for calling remove b from C and adding b to A belongs to another class. However I got the idea from code above.

Answer (score 1):

I would only use `unique_ptr` if you have to. You may prefer to make `B` a move-only type (like `unique_ptr`) to restrict ownership.

If `B` is expensive to move or it is not practical to prevent the copying of `B` then use `unique_ptr` but be aware that you are then paying for a dynamic memory allocation.

Here is how you could use a move-only `B` in an example inspired by your code. If you use `unique_ptr` instead it should work exactly the same:

```
struct B {
    B();
    B(B&&) = default;                 // Explicitly default the 
    B& operator=(B&&) = default;      // move functions.

    B(const B&) = delete;             // Delete copy functions - Not strictly 
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;  // necessary but just to be explicit.
};

struct A {
    std::vector<B> bs;
    void add(B b){
        bs.push_back(std::move(b));
    }
    B remove(std::vector<B>::iterator itr){
        B tmp = std::move(*itr);
        bs.erase(itr);
        return tmp;
    }  
};

struct C {
    A& a;
    std::vector<B> bs;
    C(A& a) : a(a) {}

    ~C(){
        for (auto& b : bs) {
            a.add(std::move(b));
        }
    }  // bs will be deleted now anyway, no need to remove the dead objects

    void add(B b){
        bs.push_back(std::move(b));
    }
    B remove(std::vector<B>::iterator itr){
        auto tmp = std::move(*itr);
        bs.erase(itr);
        return tmp;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    C c(a);
    a.add(B());
    auto tmp = a.remove(a.bs.begin());
    c.add(std::move(tmp));
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oiUyFg90aXSBTJjM)

Comment: thank you @ChrisDrew. The main reason I am using unique_ptr is learning. Otherwise it is really much easier with passing value. I wonder why c++ has pass by reference when it is so complicated...