# C++ so why error: no match for 'operator='

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So I am just trying to make an array of objects of my custom class bcLED and I am getting the error. 
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'bcLed' and 'bcLed*')

Can some one tell me why? I know it will be something simple.

also why i am here is there a way to create an array of an unspecified length in C++ and then just append it with an new row each time I want to add an object to it?

```
void PopulateLEDS(){
    int i;
    bcLed ledArr[17];
    for (i = 0; i< 16; i++)
    {
       ledArr[i] = new bcLed();
       ledArr[i].id = i;
       ledArr[i].charge = 0;
    }
}
```

OK so i need more help

To avoided creating ten thousand posts I am going to paste the main body of the code so that to see where I am tripping up with the C++ syntax.

the lattest errors are

```
/Users/bencawley/Documents/Arduino/Test/Bens_Lights/Bens_Lights.ino: In function 'void PopulateLEDS()':
Bens_Lights:49: error: expected primary-expression before 'public'
     public:bcLed ledArr[17];
     ^
Bens_Lights:52: error: 'ledArr' was not declared in this scope
        ledArr[i].id = i;
        ^
/Users/bencawley/Documents/Arduino/Test/Bens_Lights/Bens_Lights.ino: In function 'void BensPattern(uint8_t)':
Bens_Lights:69: error: 'ledArr' was not declared in this scope
       strip.setPixelColor(i,0, 0, ledArr[i].charge, 0);
                                   ^
Using library Adafruit_NeoPixel at version 1.0.6 in folder: /Users/bencawley/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_NeoPixel 
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before 'public'
```

And my code is:

```
class bcLed{
    public:int id;
    public:int charge;

    void incCharge(int amt)
    {
        charge = charge+amt;
        if(charge >= 255){charge = 255;}
    }
};

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  PopulateLEDS();
}

void loop() {
  // Some example procedures showing how to display to the pixels:
  BensPattern(45);

}

void PopulateLEDS(){
    int i;
    bcLed ledArr[17];
    for (i = 0; i< 17; i++)
    {
       ledArr[i].id = i;
       ledArr[i].charge = 0;
    }
}

void BensPattern(uint8_t wait) 
{
    uint16_t i, j;
    int rn = rand() % strip.numPixels() ;

    for (i = 0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++)
    {
      strip.setPixelColor(i,0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i<rn; i++)
    {
      strip.setPixelColor(i,0, 0, ledArr[i].charge, 0);
      ledArr[i].incCharge(1);
    }

      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
}
```

Comment: Do you come from a Java background, by any chance?

Comment: You have an array of 17 `bcLed`. You're attempting to assign a `bcLed*`. Unless you've defined a `operator=` overload for `bcLed` that takes a right-side of `bcLed*`, that isn't going to work (and you probably don't want it to anyway). You don't need that assignment statement *at all*. You already have 17 `bcLed` objects.

Comment: `ledArr[i]` is `bcLed`. `new bcLed()` returns `bcLed*`

Comment: [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Anyway, *"a way to create an array of an unspecified length in C++"* is using [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of an array.

Comment: Something java developers tend to forget when they come to C++, you have no good reason, most of the time, to use `new` (and when you do, use `delete` and `delete[]` for arrays). You don't need it here, and for dynamic memory allocation, use C++11's smart pointers.

Comment: To all those who are asking do i come from java the answer is no. I come from python and unity's C#

The only time ive ever used java was for mine craft server plugins.

Comment: Same thing goes for those langauges, `new` is always used to instantiate a new reference type. And it's cleaned up for you afterwards by the Garbage Collector. C++ doesn't offers that and just offer automatic allocation.

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla They are trying to understand why you would use the `new` keyword, which I believe means pretty much the same thing and is used in pretty much the same way in both C# and Java. Not so in C++ and I think most people would discourage you from using it, which is probably correct.

Comment: So what I understand is in C++ there is no need to use new to assign an new object to anything. And here i thought  C++ was going to be like C# :p

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla, I asked because it's a mistake I often see made by devs with Java/C# backgrounds. If you want to be proficient in C++, you need to learn it like a novice programmer. Despite the somewhat similar syntax, its night & day compared to C#/Java in terms of programming idioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` isn't always needed in C++, and definitely not here. `new` allocates dynamic memory for you if automatic allocation isn't good enough for you. You usually only use `new` if you want the variable to outlive it's scope. Memory allocated with `new` must also always be `delete`d in order to avoid a memory leak. In modern C++, the use of `new` is even less needed because we have smart pointers.

```
bcLed ledArr[17];
```

This already creates 17 `bcLed`s for you (like how you would use `new` in C#, requires no cleanup), no need to use `new` on them. Just work with them.. Your loop condition is wrong too, it's supposed to be `< 17`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
{
   ledArr[i].id = i;
   ledArr[i].charge = 0;
}
```

> also why i am here is there a way to create an array of an unspecified
>   length in C++ and then just append it with an new row each time I want
>   to add an object to it?

Yes, that's what a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is for:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<bcLed> ledArr(17);

//loop over them:
for(int i = 0; i < ledArr.size(); ++i)
{
  //ledArr[i]
}

//or:
for(std::vector<bcLed>::iterator itr = ledArr.begin() itr != ledArr.end(); ++itr)
{
  //*itr
}

// to insert to the back of the vector use push_back:

bcLed aLed;
ledArr.push_back(aLed);
```

If you have access to C++11 you can use a range based loop instead and use [`emplace_back`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back):

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<bcLed> ledArr(17);

//loop over them, just to iterate:
for(const auto& led : ledArr)
{
  //led.id
  //led.charge
}

//appending to the vector:

ledArr.emplace_back(/*constructor arguments*/);
```

---

To answer your comment

> ok im going to brave and ask this when you say "if you want the
>   variable to outlive it's scope or you're working with low level
>   memory" I don't understand what any of that means... well mostly I
>   don't understand what you mean by scope or low level memory. Could you
>   explain those? is scope the time that the method runs for?

A scope of a variable is the context in which it is defined. Automatic storage lives until the end of it's scope. Braces `{ }` indicate scope. For example:

```
void foo()
{
  int x;
  bcLed aLed;
  { //create a new inner scope
    bcLed innerLed;   
  } //scope ends, all automatic variables are destroyed (innerLed in this case)

  //can't use `innerLed` here.

  int new_int = x; 
} // scope ends, same goes, new_int, x, aLed are destroyed.
```

Really though, a good book will tell you the differences and when they should be used.

Comment: Also consider `emplace_back` to construct elements in-place in C++11.

Comment: ok im going to brave and ask this when you say "if you want the variable to outlive it's scope or you're working with low level memory" I don't understand what any of that means... well mostly I don't understand what you mean by scope or low level memory. Could you explain those? is scope the time that the method runs for?

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla : See the page about [object/reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) lifetimes on cppreference.

Comment: The "low level memory" part seems a bit awkward to me though, but I get what he means. As for the lifetime, imagine `int* a; { int b; a = &b; }` - this will produce undefined behavior, because b is supposed to be destroyed at the end of the scope. So you have to do `int* a; { a = new int(); } delete a;`. And using a unique_ptr, that will destroy its content itself: `std::unique_ptr<int> a; { a = std::make_unique<int>(); }`.

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla updated my answer. I left out the low level memory part because I feel that's not in the scope of this question. Asu did a good job of explaining it though.

Answer (score 1):

`ledArr[i] = new bcLed();` doesn't work, as the error message said, you can't assign an pointer to `bcLed` (i.e. `bcLed*`) to a `bcLed`.

For `bcLed ledArr[17];`, the 17 elements of array has been default constructed; You don't need to `new` one at all. So just remove the code causing errors, the following code would work fine.

```
bcLed ledArr[17];
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   ledArr[i].id = i;
   ledArr[i].charge = 0;
}
```

> is there a way to create an array of an unspecified length in C++ and then just append it with an new row each time I want to add an object to it?

That's what [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) supposed to do.

---

<sup>If you want to process all the elements of the array, the condition of `for` should be `i < 17`.</sup>