# Pointer to class data member

Tags: c++, pointers

In this little test program, can someone explain me:

- Why is every addresses printed in both loops the same?
- Why is it different from one loop to another?

  ```
  struct A {
      A(){ std::cout << &v << "\n"; };
      int v;
  };

  int main()
  {
      std::vector<A> vec;

      int i = 10;
      while (i--)
          vec.push_back(A());

      for (A b : vec)
          std::cout << &(b.v) << "\n";

      while (true);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

I actually expected to see ten different addresses repeated 2 times

Comment: Because `b` is a *copy* of the vector element, not the vector element itself.

Comment: Try `for (A& b : vec)` to see the address within the `vector`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i feel extremely dumb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the same addresses you need to look at the addresses inside the vector and not the addresses of temporary copies.

With `vector::emplace_back`, you can see the addresses inside the vector during the construction (see [emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back)). A reference access gives you the address inside the vector during the iterations.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;

    int i = 10;
    while (i--)
        vec.emplace_back();

    for (const A& b : vec)
        std::cout << &(b.v) << "\n";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this range based for loop :

```
    for (A b : vec)
        std::cout << &(b.v) << "\n";
```

`b` is a copy of the element in the vector. Thats why you see 10 times the same adress. It is different for two different loops, because that copy happens to be in a different memory location. You probably wanted this:

```
    for (A& b : vec)
        std::cout << &(b.v) << "\n";
```

here `b` is a reference to the element in the vector.