# Sorting a list of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

The following code will not compile:

```
bool ptrLess(unique_ptr<int> ptr1, unique_ptr<int> ptr2)
{
   return *ptr1 < *ptr2;
}

int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr2(new int(2));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr3(new int(5));
   list<unique_ptr<int>> list;

   list.push_back(ptr1);
   list.push_back(ptr2);
   list.push_back(ptr3);

   list.sort(ptrLess);

   for (auto &element : list) {
      cout << *element;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I assume this is because `unique_ptr`'s copy constructor is deleted. I get an error like:

> error C2280:
>   'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

Is there any way to sort a list of `unique_ptr`'s, perhaps by using the move constructor instead?

Comment: This looks a lot like trial-and-error C++, which does not tend to go too well. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: You can't copy unique_ptr's and ptrLess  uses pass by value so would try to create copies. Change the arguments to const refs and it should work.

Comment: @Ian4264 Would you mind creating an answer instead of a comment? I have a feeling the OP would appreciate sample code in the answer too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Could you please explain why this looks like trial-and-error? I have read Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language." I'll be honest I have only been learning C++ for a few months, but I do feel as though I understand the language pretty well.

Comment: @Zach Ok, that's a useful book at least, so it looks like my comment was not  accurate. Sorry. However, it is strange that a) your first idea when you want something sorted is to put it in a linked list and b) that your first guess for the argument type of a comparator is something other than `const &`. While it does have some oddities like his "range checked vector", I do not recall the book teaching any of that stuff wrong.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You're right, typically I would not used a linked-list if I needed to sort it later. However, this is for an exercise that my professor gave us where we need to use a linked-list for a particular algorithm. I was just wondering if I would be able to sort it at the end.

Comment: btw, you also have the class `list` and a variable `list` in the same scope, that could easily cause problems for you

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thanks you're right. I typed this up really quickly in a couple of minutes to ask this question, so I totally missed that.

Comment: @Zach Ok, then that might be your teacher's fault. As a word of advice: linked lists are very rarely useful these days because they are *awfully* slow in pretty much everything. And yes, that usually includes inserting in the middle; by the time you found the insertion point in the list, you would be long done with shifting around your `std::vector` elements. This is commonly underestimated by teaching staff it seems.

Comment: Note that if you were to use the move constructor for your `ptrLess`, then the `ptrLess` function would *own* the pointers it was comparing. Then, when the function was over, there would be no owner and the `unique_ptr` destructor would delete whatever was being pointed to. Your result would be a (technically sorted) list of null `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The performance of linked list will be poor if you use it for what it can't do well...

Comment: @curiousguy Which sadly happens to apply to the vast majority of linked list use I've seen so far. Just saying you need to have a better reason than gut-profiling for picking lists over vectors, not that they are literally always the wrong choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use const ref - after all you don't want to modify those pointers:

```
bool ptrLess(const unique_ptr<int>& ptr1, const unique_ptr<int>& ptr2)
```

If your `list` template is `std::list`, then passing arguments as r-value references won't work - `list::sort` would have to call `std::move` effectively resetting your pointers.

**Edit**

As for list the rest of your code: `std::list` has a handy method called `emplace_back` (and `emplace_front`) which allows you to construct and append an element in-place:

```
your_list.emplace_back(new int(2));
```

Comment: And, _because of the way the list is declared_, it takes ownership of the object passed in, right?  Neato, I like it, but (for me, at least) you need to make clear what that innocent looking one-liner actually does.  It's [unusual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) to pass a newly-constructed object to that method (in this case it is passed on to `unique_ptr` as an argument to the constructor so it's OK, it will get deleted in due course).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace ::std;

bool ptrLess(unique_ptr<int>& ptr1, unique_ptr<int>& ptr2)
{
   return *ptr1 < *ptr2;
}

int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr2(new int(2));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr3(new int(5));
   list<unique_ptr<int>> list;

   list.push_back(move(ptr1));
   list.push_back(move(ptr2));
   list.push_back(move(ptr3));

   list.sort(ptrLess);

   for (auto &element : list) {
      cout << *element;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that you need to understand what a `unique_ptr` actually aims to be:

When dealing with pointers/references, there are a hell lot of potential problems arising if there are several pointersrs/references referring to the same object.
`unique_ptr` tries to avoid precisely that.
Therefore, you cannot create 2 `unique_ptr` referring to the same object.

You cannot use your `ptrLess()` function because calling it like

```
   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr2(new int(2));

   ptrLess(ptr1, ptr2);
```

because this would mean `ptr1` an `ptr2` would have to be copied and passed over to `ptrLess()` - keyword here is 'call-by-value'.

Moreover, you cannot do

```
   list<unique_ptr<int>> list;
   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));

   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
```

because this too, would have to create a copy of `ptr1`.
The solution here is to not pass the `unique_ptr` s to `ptrLess` as values, but as reference:

```
bool ptrLess(unique_ptr<int>& ptr1, unique_ptr<int>& ptr2);
```

And you dont pass copies into the list, but *move* your object there:

```
list.push_back(move(ptr1));
```

keyword here is 'move-semantics'.
This will invalidate the content of your `ptr1` variable - the object has been moved out of `ptr1` into the list.

I recommend having a look at the Rust language if you are more deeply interested in things like these ;)

As Baum mit Augen pointed out, the parameters to `ptrLess` better be declared as `const`:

```
bool ptrLess(const unique_ptr<int>& ptr1, const unique_ptr<int>& ptr2);
```

Comment: At least this compiles, but a comparator should not use non-const reference and, more importantly, using a linked list to sort some values is not the right approach. You should address and explain that.

Comment: Also, what does Rust have to do with any of this?

Comment: You are right, my answer is not optimal - but I cannot unclude every aspect in the answer - otherwise I would end up like Donald Knuth ;)

Comment: Incorporated your remark about const parameters. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @MichaelBeer: In depth detail somewhat somewhere and made jump over to Rust and finally the code compiled.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Its all about ownership, one of Rusts core concepts ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try passing by const ref so it won't copy the parameters :
bool ptrLess(const unique_ptr& ptr1, const unique_ptr& ptr2) { return *ptr1 < *ptr2; }

Answer (score -1):

It occurs to me to suggest that if the OP uses `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` then the code as originally posted will otherwise run unchanged:

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace ::std;

bool ptrLess(const shared_ptr<int>& ptr1, const shared_ptr<int>&  ptr2)
{
   return *ptr1 < *ptr2;
}

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
   shared_ptr<int> ptr2(new int(2));
   shared_ptr<int> ptr3(new int(5));
   list<const shared_ptr<int>> list;

   list.push_back(ptr1);
   list.push_back(ptr2);
   list.push_back(ptr3);

   list.sort(ptrLess);

   for (auto &element : list) {
      cout << *element;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Run it on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9stSn0MmFh1T0mZU).

In some senses, this is a consistent way to do things.  `push_back` would normally copy the object being added to the list, leaving the original object still available to the caller should he or she want to use it.  Using `shared_ptr` has similar semantics without the overhead of copying the object itself.  Instead, just the `shared_ptr` is copied, which is a cheap operation.

Also, modifying the OP's original code to `move` the `unique_ptrs` into the list is inherently fragile.  They remain in scope to the caller but are no longer usable.  You will get (I assume) a `nullptr` dereference if you try.  Better then, to do this (note the extra set of braces):

```
...

list<unique_ptr<int>> list;

{
   unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(3));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr2(new int(2));
   unique_ptr<int> ptr3(new int(5));

   list.push_back(move(ptr1));
   list.push_back(move(ptr2));
   list.push_back(move(ptr3));
}

...
```

Now you are safe.

There, that's a much better post than the original version, sorry about that.

Comment: I was trying to provide the MCVE. It's for a project where I have to write a function that takes a list of unique_pointers of objects and performs an operation on it. I figured that it was unnecessary to talk about what the object was and what the operation is that I am performing (it happens to involve a sort). All I was asking was how to sort it.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for `ptrLess` to have ownership of the pointers. Making them shared so it can own pointers it doesn't need to own is a bad idea; better to express the lack of ownership with `unique_ptr<int> const&`.

Comment: @DanielH What you say about passing a const ref to `ptrLess` is quite right and I have amended my answer.  But you have missed the point.  The _list_ needs to ensure that the objects pushed onto it remain valid for as long as it needs access to them and that is precisely what `shared_ptr` is designed for.  Using `unique_ptr` for any kind of object to be stored in an STL container is asking for trouble.  Stop and think for a moment: what happens if the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope before the container does?

Comment: @PaulSanders If you have a list of `unique_ptr`s, the pointers *won't* go out of scope unless you remove them from the list or explicitly transfer them. The *list* owns the pointers; that's the point of them. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to do if for some reason you need to transfer the objects between containers without calling their move constructors, or the type you're pointing to doesn't fit all the requirements of the container, or probably other cases. It's not a usual thing to do because you'd usually just store the type directly and indirection costs overhead, but it isn't unsafe.

Comment: @Zach Sorry, I didn't mean to beat you up, I just wanted to point out that your list can just be a simple list of int's.  Try implementing that - everything will get much simpler.

Comment: @PaulSanders To move from a `unique_ptr` you need to call `move`; it doesn't happen accidentally and you can deliberately break anything. The typical advice (eg. [CPP core guidelines F.27](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-shared_ptr), [GotW 89 Q. 1](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/), [this CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE?t=2m43s)) is to use `shared_ptr` only when you *need* shared ownership; in this case, having the list own the `int`s is better (which is also why you prefer `list<int>` to any sort of list of pointers).

Comment: @DanielH Oh right, if you move them in there then yes, sorry. That's fine as long as you don't need them for anything else.  You have to be careful though. As you yourself pointed out above, passing (references to) unique_ptr's around is fragile, lest they get moved again. shared_ptr is flexible, safe and almost as efficient.

Comment: @DanielH Fair enough, I stand corrected.  I guess, in any particular instance, it comes down to whether you want access to the objects after you have added them to the list or not, simple as that.

Comment: @PaulSanders All good. I know that a list of int's would be simpler. I purposely made it that way to reflect some code I have to complete for a project where I don't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: @Zach Cool, thank you.  I think I underestimated you.

Comment: @DanielH I reworked my post, I'd be the first to admit that the tone was all wrong.  Thanks for your input.  I learnt a few things.