# How can I make pair using vector in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I am having difficulty pushing two integers as a pair in vector. I'd like to know where it went wrong. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector <pair<int,int>> vec;
    int s,n; cin>>s>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int in1,in2; cin>>in1>>in2;
        vec[i].push_back(make_pair(in1,in2));
    }
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    int checker=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(s<=vec[i].first){
            checker=0;
            break;
        }
        else{
            s+=vec[i].second;
        }
    }
    if(checker>0)cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    else if(checker==0)cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you get a compiler error? Please include it in the question

Comment: did You mean `vec.push_back(make_pair(in1,in2));`?

Comment: @Kamiccolo i added [i] to specify the index, but is that a problem here?

Comment: `vec[i]` is a pair but you want to push into the vector not into a pair. Also there is no element at index `i` before you add one

Comment: Yes, I have understood the problem here. My code works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
vec[i].push_back(make_pair(in1, in2));
```

to

```
vec.push_back(make_pair(in1, in2));
```

Also, if you change the order of these two lines:

```
    vector <pair<int,int>> vec;
    int s,n; cin>>s>>n;
```

and reserve `size` of the vector, you will not have to reallocate memory every time you do a `push_back`. This will make your program more efficient:

```
    int s,n; cin>>s>>n;
    //preallocate for 'n' elements
    vector <pair<int,int>> vec;
    vec.reserve(n);
```

Comment: Yes, I have understood the problem here. My code works now. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth to mention that you cannot combine second advice with first one. You need to either use `reserve()` if you want to continue using `push_back` or use `operator[]` if vector was created with `n` elements.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen indeed. I updated to use `reserve()` instead as it is simpler and more straightforward

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax of pushing a value in a vector is : `vectorname.push_back(value)`.

So,
you need to write `vec.push_back(make_pair(in1,in2));` instead of

`vec[i].push_back(make_pair(in1,in2))`.

If you need to ***insert the pair at specific index*** then you will have to use `insert` function instead of `push_back` because `push_back` inserts the element at the end of the vector.

To ***insert at i'th index*** kindly use:

`vec.insert(vec.begin() + i, make_pair(int1, int2))`.

Comment: Yes, I have understood the problem here. My code works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid making unnecessary copies of `std::pair`, you may want to construct `std::pair` in place by using [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```cpp
vec.emplace_back(in1, in2);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand it. I will have to look into it more.

Comment: @FahimHassan when using `vec.push_back(make_pair(in1, in2));`, an object is being created with `make_pair(in1, in2)`. Then this object is copied to the `std::vector`. With `emplace_back`, this copy is avoided and, thus, you end up with better performance. Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back).

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks!