# c++ when working with class containing vectors - candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
class myItem {
    int key;
    string name;
    
    public:
    // Constructor
    myItem(int key, string name)
    {
        key = key;
        name = name;
    }
};

class myCollection {
    vector<myItem> col;
    public:
        void insert(myItem &i);
        void print();
};

int main() {
    myCollection c;
    int key;
    string name;
    cin >> key;
    cin >> name;
    myItem i = myItem(key, name);
    c.insert(i);
    c.print();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error: no matching function for call to ‘myItem::myItem()’ and note: candidate: myItem::myItem(int, std::string). candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided. How might I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `void insert(&i);` isn't a valid class member function declaration.

Comment: There's a felt gazillion [other error messages](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4691f397f083fd54) issued by your code, but not the one you claim.

Comment: Which line is that error happening on? There's no call like that in the code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, with the question as now edited, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LSSM2dzGD64p5Yg3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The vector you are using in myCollection internally uses the default constructor. Try using a pointer of myItem in the vector or specify the default and copy constructors too.

Comment: See [push_back vs emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) please.. _"Try using a pointer of myItem in the vector"_ this is certainly the worst advice you can give about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not a fan of confusing the compiler with similar names. This is terrible practice (and I am not a fan of the java **this.local = param**)

And even if you can argue the compiler *knows* what is right, someone maintaining your code will not. So you could at least capitalize or suffic and underscore or something else if you don't want to rename (sometimes I saw prefixing it with in, like inKey, inName as an alternative method which I am all in favor for, the underscore is a good if you don't want to make the name change to stand out, just make sure the underscore is not in front of the variable/parameter name):

```
int key;
string name;

public:
// Constructor
myItem(int key_, string name_) : key(key_), name(name_) {}
```

Moving on, I don't get your error but I do get unresolved externals. The problem is myCollection is defined, but not implemented (or rather its methods aren't). Try an empty placeholder using **{}**.

```
class myCollection {
vector<myItem> col;
public:
    void insert(myItem &i) {}
    void print() {}
};
```

This should fix your errors.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I like your inline initialization, I didn't want to complicate his code since I think she's a beginner. I'll edit the text to reflect underscores too, I admit they might be a better choice here.

Comment: I just wanted to correct the failing `**` bold specifiers in code formatted text, but well, if I am at it. I also thought about that the constructor initializer list might confuse the OP further, so you're probably right to change that back again.

Answer (score -1):

Your Constructor is named `Team` and not `myItem`

Replace it with

```
myItem(int key, string name)
{
  key = key;
  name = name;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was an error when I edit the code - my constructor is named myItem