# Difference between vector::push_back(Foo()) and vector::emplace_back(Foo())?

Tags: c++, std

I understand that with `emplace_back` you provide it constructor arguments, and with `push_back` you provide it with a copy from which to copy. However when passing the type that the element type of the vector it seems to me that they might be the same, because `emplace_back` will move-construct in place with the copy you provide, which is what `push_back` does, right?

Unless `push_back` default constructs a new object, and then uses `operator=` to move the argument. In that case they would be different.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4303834/12257925) answers your question (if I understood it right). If i didn't, don't hesitate to let me know

Comment: In libstdc++ [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L1293-L1294), `push_back()` overload that takes `value_type&&` dispatches the call to `emplace_back()`, so there is no difference at all.